# Comments that a problem is part of a live contest (and thus, cheating) get removed?

Tags: discussion, comments

Unfortunately we often see questions about live programming competitions on Stack Overflow. Of course Stack Overflow does not have any rules against that so they won't get closed or deleted. I can understand the reasoning and necessity of this.

Now I personally and at least one other user on [algorithm] that I know of have had bad experiences where we unknowingly posted more or less complete solutions for problems from running contests, somewhat spoiling the overall fun. We want to avoid that in the future.

I have thus made it a habit to at least look at some particularly popular monthly long-term competitions to know what the problems are and avoid answering questions about those. If I see one, I often write a comment like "Fellow users, note that this is a question from a running contest (link) so think twice before answering". So that *if people care*, they at least *know* what is up. For me it is extremely helpful if somebody detects this and points it out, because if I write an answer, it will be on a much higher level, similar to some homework answers.

Yesterday I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259298/path-of-length-n-in-graph-with-constraints) and did the same thing, pointed out that it is from a live HackerRank contest that ends today.

My comment was *deleted* by a moderator without comment. It went like this (paraphrased from memory):

> Oh, so you're solving HackerRank too. I'm also working on that problem right now (link). Community, please don't spoil the fun for the participants

Even a comment I wrote later, which was a response to Nikunj's question, was *deleted*. It went like

> Yes, it's from a live contest. See my earlier comment for a link

A comment asking the anonymous moderator why the comment was deleted was *deleted*.

> Moderator, please clarify why my initial comment was deleted

I have to say, this silent deletion thing is really upsetting, it makes one feel very helpless. I can totally understand that it is necessary as a tool, but why was it used in this scenario? It just feels very wrong to me. Also I want these comments from others and *don't want them to be deleted*.

Is this going to be handled this way in the future too? Can somebody explain the reasoning behind this? Can the responsible moderator maybe say anything about what happened there?

**EDIT:** After ChrisF's comment, another question arises: If indeed it is the case that the probability that such a comment gets deleted for being unconstructive, then what other means do we have to communicate information like this with other members of the community? I figure there is none.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Unless you used offensive language, this seems weird

Comment: @Pekka웃 Not at all. I will add a paraphrased version of them to the question

Comment: OK, so let me clarify. I thought that most of the "programming contests" that happen on stack exchange are on the [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) site. I was not aware that such contests happen on SO.

Comment: The comments were flagged as not constructive. I wasn't the moderator who deleted them so I can't say *why* they were deleted, but they were only deleted because they were flagged.

Comment: @gunr2171 The contest is run by *another* non Stack Exchange site. The question on SO was an attempt to get help with the code for that contest.

Comment: @ChrisF I'm well aware that OP has flagged them, I'm wondering why they were removed. "Not constructive" might be the reason, but without any other means of communicating meta-information like this about a question, what choice do we have? Closing is not an option, neither is flagging the question for moderator attention.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I want other people who care to know, just as I want to know if other people spot something like this

Comment: *"A comment asking the anonymous moderator why the comment was deleted was deleted."* Well, yeah ... it wasn't contributing to clarifying or improving the post it was associated with.

Comment: @dmckee Well yeah, that part actually didn't surprise me that much ;)

Comment: @smci To be fair I didn't say that. I just suggested people not to answer, which admittedly is somewhat counterproductive. I will make sure to add the end date and time of a contest when writing such a comment in the future

Comment: It's not necessary or relevant to point out that a question is from/related to a live contest.  In all probability in the time it took to post the question and wait for an answer a more qualified contest participant has already come up with their own solution.  I don't see much benefit in calling people out for posting something that appears to be a contest question.  It follows that such comments would be candidates for deletion since they're not adding much value.

Comment: @aroth I just realized I misinterpreted your comment. Sure it might not get you among the top-K, but you still gain an unfair advantage over other weaker participants.

Comment: @aroth For example in the [CodeChef March Long-Term Challenge](http://www.codechef.com/MARCH14/) the tasks GERALD07 and STREETA were only solved by ~100 people in total out of >5000 registered participants. The solutions can be found on Stack Overflow because we unknowingly answered answers about it. From what I know, success on sites like CodeChef actually matters at least in the Indian IT community and can affect your real life, so I consider this relevant.

Comment: @NiklasB. - "you still gain an unfair advantage over other weaker participants" Perhaps, though likely only over participants who also cannot solve the problem themselves.  So maybe someone gets to be ranked 89th instead of being in a 4910-way tie for 90th.  And maybe they deserve that for finding an open-source solution to the problem where those 4910 others just gave up.  Is a public, multi-week contest the best example?  All it takes is one blog post and the cat is out of the bag anyways.  And Codechef has a policy for dealing with cheaters.  Shouldn't they manage their own enforcement?

Comment: @aroth This is not about enforcing the rules of the contest. This is about me (and potentially others) personally being unwilling to answer such questions, but not being able to spot them (because there are lots of legitimate questions about tasks that are used by people for practice). Comments are a way to communicate the source, so that people can base their decision on whether to write a complete answer on that

Comment: I just want to say that the 'not constructive' flag is short for 'not constructive criticism', and is not for off topic comments. Flagging it as such is wrong, if not just an abuse of authority.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As someone who sometimes spends a lot of time answering an SO question, I personally would find it *very constructive* if someone let me know that the question was part of an open competition and that my effort might be used for someone to gain unfair advantage.

That said, given the text of your original comment, I can understand why it might have got deleted.  You started with a slightly snide chatty comment that didn't add anything to the discussion ("So you're solving HackerRank too?") and ended with a "please don't answer" to the community.

I can understand your frustration if you've seen this happen many times, but remember that other people coming across the question (including the moderators) may not be familiar with that history.

To answer *your* question,

> "what other means do we have to communicate information like this with other members of the community?"

I would say that comments are the appropriate means to do so, but try to squelch your frustration and make the comment as "constructive" as possible, focusing on informing other users rather than telling them what to do or making digs at the OP.

A possibility:

> FYI to everyone that this question is currently part of [name of competition, with link], which is active until [end date].  If you're interested in the problem, you might want to submit your solution to that contest.  **I'd also appreciate it if everyone would think twice about posting complete answers here until after the competition close date.**

If you really think the poster is trolling for a ready-made answer (as opposed to just honestly being stumped by a puzzle and impatient for the solution), you might get away with wording it

> An important detail you forgot to mention is that this question is currently part of [name of competition] which is active until [end date].  For anyone else interested in the problem... (etc. as above)

Again, the idea is to word it so that you're adding more information for other users (constructive), not having a side-conversation about your frustrations with a contest run by another site (un-constructive).

Comment: Thank you Amelia, your answer is helpful. I wasn't really frustrated because of the question, I guess I just didn't think hard enough before writing the comment :)

Comment: I don’t think there was a problem with the original comments. I like to know people here have personalities and are human. It saddens me to see how this site is changing.

Comment: @CharlieGorichanaz  Honestly, I agree, and certainly wouldn't recommend deleting a comment just because it was a little chatty or a little critical (many of my comments would fail that test!).  But in the context of the answers from the moderators who did make that choice, I was trying to suggest an approach to get the information across without hitting any "un-constructive" triggers.

Comment: Feature-request that specifically fixes this scenario http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252676/is-there-a-need-for-a-new-flag-type-embargoed-until-contest-closes-at-date-ti

Answer (score 20):

**There's a world of a difference between suggesting people *never* answer, vs suggesting people *not answer until the contest is over***

namely Mon Apr 28 2014, 16:00 UTC in this case. The latter seems perfectly reasonable (and constructive) to me.

I (and other people here) emphatically disagree with George Stocker's blanket answer which tries to conflate the two. I totally disagree with George's reasoning for claiming the latter is unconstructive. How on earth is waiting like all of (up to) 1-7 days to answer going to make things worse in any way? It's not.

SO should give better guidance about what comment/flagging behavior is acceptable, on open competitions.

Two possibilities I see:

1. Leave it open, but mark prominently at top 'part of open competition X which closes at D/T'.
2. An *embargo Flag: suspend until* , with link to competition, might also be useful.

As to NiklasB's specific comment exchange, I haven't seen it and can't comment. But, we need guidance. I appreciate that people like NiklasB are vigilant on this. People who are looking to cheat on online competitions (which is rife) are unlikely to self-identify, let alone return and become valuable regular contributors.

I posted this enhance request at ***[Is there a need for a new flag type: 'Embargoed until contest closes at <date/time>'?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252676/is-there-a-need-for-a-new-flag-type-embargoed-until-contest-closes-at-date-ti)***

Comment: Actually it was only until the next day (Apr 25 in that case). I absolutely see that I should have added the specific time and date. I also added an answer after that, explaining my solution

Comment: Ok then that's the best-practice. Many people support you.

Answer (score 19):

I deleted some comments from that post a few hours after the first few were deleted. As they were part of a conversation that was half deleted, I didn't think they made sense without the context of the deleted content.

As for why the original comments were deleted, I understand wanting to enforce the rules of the contest site, but asking people to not answer a question on Stack Overflow isn't constructive *to our purpose here*. People come here for answers to homework, real work, and even programming contest questions. You're well within your rights to not answer them or to even downvote them for whatever reason you choose, but we can't support comments that encourage people to close or not answer questions that are within our own rules and guidelines.

Comment: Comments pointing out the source of the problem and that it's from a live contest would be fine?

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, I don't see any harm in that. You might even want to include the contest end date.

Comment: Contests should be monitoring these kinds of things, anyway. SE isn't a small thing anymore; it's a vital tool for almost *anyone* doing *anything* development related.

Comment: @Qix: Yes I brought this up in the CodeChef forums after the March challenge and the reaction was that the community was a bit surprised about this. I guess they didn't expect a lot of expertise in the subject to be found at any place where might not know about the current "big" competitions, but there are quite some people with competitive programming (and general algorithms) background specifically on Stack Overflow.