# Graying out downvoted answers in meta discussion questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, downvotes, meta

A lot of posts marked with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) are rather controversial, and so is the voting on answers. However I think that the meta community partly lives from this diversity, and since downvoting on those kind of answers doesn't represent *wrong* but rather *disagreement* their presentation and accessibility shouldn't suffer from negative vote counts.

Unfortunately at a certain limit, answers with negative vote count are greyed out.

Therefore I propose that we either

- completely remove the grey out on meta
- remove the grey out depending on the presence of [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion)
- increase the downvotes limit upon which an answer is greyed out on meta.

<sub>To save the hassle to look some up, [here is a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252013/comments-that-a-problem-is-part-of-a-live-contest-get-removed?cb=1#252019) to see how an answer currently looks like.</sub>

Comment: Similar requests are still alive on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142628/shouldnt-downvoted-answers-on-meta-be-non-transparent-instead-of-semi-transpare

Comment: @Bart: So time to revive it? Anyways I am unable to say if its a good idea for all metas, as I don't know if downvoting is perceived there the same way. Also implementing it as an increased downvotes limit might make it better to adapt for specific metas.

Comment: I dumped a bounty on it. Let's see if that sparks some additional attention and input.

Comment: FYI @plasmahh http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230657/161198

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is done. The new threshold is **-8**.

You realize this just means y'all have to down-vote *that much harder* now, right?

Comment: Lets keep this secret for us ;)

Comment: I will _love_ to downvote here (where the downvotes are free :-) )