# Are we abusing our delete votes on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, vote-to-delete

Someone posted [this rant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267963/456814) earlier today:

> #### Stack Overflow encourages people not to think
>
> So many rules that may work for 90% of the time, but there will always
>   be edge cases where they fail. But whatever.
>
> If I ask an uncommon question here people are unable to conceive its
>   use cases and label it XY problem. This shows that you lack the
>   ability to think creatively.
>
> I don't know.. maybe it's not just Stack Overflow. For example I haven't seen a good
>   movie in ages. Everywhere just shallow transformer-style crap. What's
>   happening with you people?!

I voted to delete it, and it reminded me that I should take a peek at the [current pending delete votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools) around on Meta to see if there's any other junk that I could help clean up.

When I started poking around the pending deletions, however, I began to notice posts that maybe shouldn't(?) be deleted:

[image: Screenshot]

1. [Should we add RTFM to the list of off-topic close reasons?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253473/should-we-add-rtfm-to-the-list-of-off-topic-close-reasons/253490#253490)

   > No, because Googling is itself a skill that beginners often don't
   >   have, and you can't really blame them.
   >
   > It takes a while to learn it and have it really sink in. I've been
   >   through it, I know. You probably have too.
2. [close-reason suggestion: closing a question where the asker wants others to do his homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250867/close-reason-suggestion-closing-a-question-where-the-asker-wants-others-to-do-h/250873#250873)

   > While I personally disagree with the removal of that close reason, a
   >   downvote kinda means the same thing. The help text when you hover over
   >   a downvote says:
   >
   > > This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful
   >
   > And a comment stating that we need more information (for example, what they've
   >   previously tried) to answer the question never goes amiss.
3. [Filtering questions by "difficulty" / "level"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253338/filtering-questions-by-difficulty-level/262776#262776)
4. [Filtering questions by "difficulty" / "level"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253338/filtering-questions-by-difficulty-level/253344#253344)
5. [How often are closed questions re-opened?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266709/how-often-are-closed-questions-re-opened/266733#266733)
6. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267483/stack-overflow-in-decline

   This last one *is not a rant*. It's a very neutral, innocent question that merely seeks to understand why it looks like [user are answering fewer questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions).

The posts above that I linked to are examples where **people's opinions are being deleted**. The [Help Center guidance for deleting answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) says:

> #### You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
>
> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

When I cast delete votes on answers, it's because the answer is offensive, or it's not an answer (i.e. a comment, etc.). As I've already mentioned, many of the posts above are legitimate answers that are expressing people's opinions.

**Are we deleting answers merely out of disagreement?** *Should* we be doing that? Deleting junk like [this rant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267963/456814) that I pointed out earlier seems to be much more important, but I could be wrong.

One of my biggest issues with these pending deletes is that it makes it harder to find the worst junk that needs to be deleted. The 10k mod tools aren't as good as the review queues for this, in my personal experience.

### More examples of *really* bad posts that should be deleted (10k+ only)

- [Junk 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267974/456814)
- [Junk 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267972/456814)

Comment: "Are we deleting answers merely out of disagreement?" - Yes. "Should we be doing that?" - No. "Is there much we can do about it?" - Nope. :)

Comment: @Mysticial my biggest issue with it is that it makes it harder to find the crap that should *actually* be deleted, as I've tried to point out in my screenshot.

Comment: StackOverflow should most certainly be renamed to [Groupthink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink). It was a *great* idea to start with, but it has ended up being run by the High Reputation Mafia (not entirely surprisingly).

Comment: *Are we deleting answers merely out of disagreement?* Yes. Another consequence of the behavior on meta that downvotes are used for 'disagree' instead of 'bad question' (thereby losing the distinction between those two; and in contrast with what we do on the main site). But [that discussion has been going on for a long time](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus). So it's not so much abuse as it is misuse. Sadly, the majority seems to disagree.

Comment: I agree with that rant completely.

Comment: see also: [Can we slow down on the deletes on Meta, folks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405585/839601)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I took a look at the posts with pending delete votes here (~19 answers) and those that've been deleted by vote at some point (20 answers).

For the most part, we're not actually deleting anything of value. And of course, 10K users can verify this by checking [the list of recently-deleted posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete) now and then.

However, I tend to think delete votes hanging around on controversial answers are somewhat counter-productive, even if they don't actually result in the post being deleted. [This question provides a good example of this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no) - 4 answers with delete votes. None of these answers are inappropriate for a meta **discussion**, they're just unpopular. In [one case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no/252664#252664), the answer attracted **17 upvotes**, which were slightly outweighed by 23 downvotes. Frankly, this is a bit ridiculous.

A while back, [we dropped the "gray it out" threshold to -8 here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252529/graying-out-downvoted-answers-in-meta-discussion-questions/252614#252614), after y'all expressed concern that it was just deemphasizing slightly unpopular opinions at its previous threshold. Philosophically, I think it makes sense to do the same with the threshold for vote-to-delete eligibility.

**Therefore, I've dropped the threshold for voting to delete an answer here to -8** - practically-speaking, this isn't going to change much, but I think it sends the right message to folks participating here.

Note that this does *not* affect deletions triggered via flags, so it shouldn't be making it any harder to get rid of spam or actual non-answers.

Comment: Of course a technical solution is the way to fix a behavior problem. :)

Comment: eh, as others pointed out here, the only real problem *was* technical - we leave these votes around cluttering up the place even when there's no consensus on them.

Comment: Can we just let delete votes age away like close votes do? If someone feels strongly enough to recast, let them do it.

Comment: We *could* - this hasn't been a big problem outside of a few edge-cases though, so we haven't bothered.

Comment: Votes-to-close and votes-to-delete aren't really tools for measuring consensus, though, are they?  I mean, unless you have an axiom that there is only one possible consensus and it is that the post should be closed/deleted?  There's no corresponding vote-to-don't-close or vote-to-don't-delete.

Comment: Not directly, @tmyklebu. The immediate effect of VtC and VtD is to prevent someone from going rogue and acting contrary to what others feel is appropriate; think of it as a variation on [the two-man rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-man_rule). As a consequence, voting according to generally-accepted community norms tends to be more *effective* than voting contrary to them, but that does not mean that every closure or deletion will reflect consensus - hence the systems for reopening and undeletion.

Comment: @Shog9: Instead of setting it to a hard value, why don't you base it on [this](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html)? Set it to something like 5% likelihood or something.

Comment: Because it's just not that big of an issue, @Mehrdad. This setting took me less time to change than writing up an answer saying I changed it, so it doesn't matter much that it only affects a tiny, tiny fraction of posts. It'd have to be a much bigger problem to justify changing the criteria for deletion.

Comment: Do you consider this so much of a corner case that it isn't [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)? There is a [request to update the help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295681/answer-deletion-on-meta-stack-overflow) but that might have gone unnoticed, at least by me.

Comment: To alter the help center, I would have to split off the help page for Stack Overflow and add an exception for meta, or add an exception for MSO to the help center for *every* site; there's no MSO-specific help center, @rene. So yes, this is too much of a corner case to bother a majority of readers about.

Answer (score 8):

You are specifically looking at posts that have not been deleted despite getting a delete vote *in the past 30 days*.

So it's quite possible they indeed shouldn't be deleted: Someone voted for deletion several days ago and nobody else agreed. So the posts aren't getting deleted, which agrees with your concern that they shouldn't be.

Comment: True, but then they seem to stick around the 10k mod tools forever, making it harder to find stuff that actually should be deleted. I'm trying to find if delete votes actually expire. Now that you bring up the timeframe resolution though, I guess if I reduce the frame to a day or two, or a week at most, I'd actually be able to surface more problematic posts and less of the legitimate stuff that we should keep, huh?

Comment: [Delete votes don't expire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/163250), but using a smaller window to look for them definitely makes it easier to find problem posts.

Answer (score 4):

A delete vote is not a delete.

This is the reason that we have multiple votes for things like closure and deletion: to get community consensus.  Absent that consensus, no action is taken.

Accordingly, I regard questions about delete votes and close votes, on posts that have not been deleted or closed, as premature.

Comment: One of the issues I see with it is that it makes it more difficult to actually find posts that *should* be deleted. Should I make that clearer in my question, or is it not even worth bringing up?

Comment: Don't delete votes age away eventually?  Can't remember.  I do hear what you are saying about the rogue delete votes clogging that queue.

Comment: [Delete votes don't expire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/163250), but [sth pointed out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268042/456814) that things that shouldn't really will stick around longer (I was using the 30 day timeframe), so if I use a smaller window (like 1 or 2 days), that should more easily surface the actual problematic posts.