# If Stack Overflow is about building a Q&A library - how to communicate and uphold that?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-comments

I love Stack Overflow and it has helped me tremendously. I have only asked 25 questions, but I cannot count the number of times an existing Q&A has been helpful for me. I am a firm believer that the primary objective of this site is to *build a library* of Q&A to which *helping the asker* is a secondary goal. I always thought that there is [some consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) about that.

Sometimes, if a question is not clear enough to me, I refrain from answering a question even though I am almost sure that I have an answer that helps the asker. Instead I try to help improve the question through comments and edits - if that fails I try to filter through close and downvotes. This is often frustrating, but a recent event leaves me baffled.

A question with incomplete code and a non-verbatim error message

> *init called after *finalize invoked

which overall leads me to believe this error is just the tip of the iceberg. Anyway, an answer consisting of

> *INIT() and *FINALIZE can only be called once per program, as your error hints at.

and an referenced copy of another answer comes in. The asker seems happy with the answer while I suspect they still may have misconceptions - more importantly I believe the current Q&A would be useless or possibly dangerously confusing to anyone else.

Now these comments unfold:

---

[image: chain of comments]

---

The last two comments are now deleted.

The asker is a longtime user with > 200 questions on SO. They now have confirmation that the primary purpose of SO is to answer their questions rather than building a Q&A library.

Why was my last comment deleted? Was it not in line with the site philosophy or was it really abusive?

Is the primary purpose of SO still to build a Q&A library? If so, how can we communicate that better?

Comment: Was that last comment by you deleted by a mod? That's certainly strange, there's nothing rude or abusive about it in my opinion.

Comment: Well it wasn't deleted by me, so I assume it was a mod. I have not received any mod-feedback.

Comment: To address just the comments (your question about how to better educate users as to the goal of the site is a much more difficult question): The two comments were deleted due to a comment flag. It was clear that the OP had read your comment, and as such had served its purpose. I didn't mean to leave the thread in a state which re-enforced their side of the argument. I *should* have deleted their (now last) comment as well, but I guess I must have been distracted... Sorry about that.

Comment: Since the comment is already captured here, I'll delete it now. In any case, your comment was not abusive, despite their claim. If you were not contacted by a moderator, you've nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Rob but I guess the flagger had their flag marked as helpful, so they will continue to believe they were right to flag the comment as abusive and as such will flag others as well

Comment: This sounds like yet another case of abuse towards curators. I cannot think of anything that you could have changed in this interaction (other than just stopping before escalating, which sometimes we cannot even predict). At this point I just wonder if that OP's flag was marked as "helpful" or "declined".

Comment: @Adelin I could have gone out of my way to decline the flag and then delete the comment, but declined comment flags don't contribute to flag warnings or bans, and the flagging page isn't exactly discoverable, so it's unlikely they would have noticed. We don't even get to leave a reason for declining flags.

Comment: @Zulan, I commend your commitment to educating users. I've given up and just go with the flow. Mark as a duplicate if I know a good canonical, answer with an explanation if it's answerable, or VTC. In my experience, educating can't be reinforced if users are getting their poor questions answered (that's *all* most of them care about). Mods can't do much either. The `[tag]` community has to care, what I mean by this is you need to be able to tell the community (e.g. via chat) that there's a poor question, and they need to react by mass close votes *before* the poor question gets answered.

Comment: @Rob _"It was clear that the OP had read your comment, and as such had served its purpose"_ - so you can flag a comment as "no longer needed" to "mark as read" and get it removed? Even if the recipient has not taken any action on it, while they should've?

Comment: @CodeCaster Well... people are not *obliged* to take the advice of a comment. There's no use in having a comment thread of debate if it's clear nothing productive is going to come from it. Especially if it starts generating flags. I personally will tend to leave one or two constructive comments remaining (if there are any) to prevent future visitors from leaving the same feedback on the post - or if the comment is, for example, pointing out a flaw in an answer. If comments are the root of dispute between users, there's no point keeping them around.

Comment: You're right, but you'll never, ever win that battle with an OP who holds this mindset. I long ago stopped trying. Sadly this also IMO means that -- to not-really-but-sort-of-answer the question in your title, _we can't_, and that's probably why the saturation of the site has left it being quite far from a nice repo of questions, and why the team has started turning it into a "welcoming" social media platform instead :P

Comment: Yup - SO, as it was, is over. No measure. suggested so far. will reduce the number of rep-whatevers answering bad questions while, at the same time, not reduce SO ad-view revenue stream.  It's homework-dumps all the way down:(   The squad of curators can level the descent a bit by putting in more effort on dupe-linking bad questions than the army of OP's do on copy/pasting them, but that kind of tide-stemming is not sustainable, so why bother?

Comment: You're not wrong though. This site's primary goal is so people can help themselves. Unfortunately, there is and as it seems always will be a gaping disconnect between goal and what people feel entitled to use the site for. The goal: that people *Find all the answers!* What people want to do: *Ask all the questions!* Any inkling that asking was the wrong thing to do... well it ranges from mild discontent to a disturbance in the force. The answering part of the equation has the mirror effect of it where people *Answer all the questions!* rather than *Find all the existing answers!*

Comment: This is not something new, this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/5292302) will summarize this old problem. My advice when you see people are not interested to listen to your comments, disengage and move on, further comments will only create distress and more stuff to clean up for "caretakers", *as in one of the answers below*

Comment: @MartinJames homework dumps are not by definition off-topic though and have never been. It might be that we need to adopt a little more leniency to such questions, within limits. Those limits are yet to be properly defined. I wouldn't have much of a problem with it, money needs to be earned to keep this monster afloat so let the ad revenue do its magic. Just as long as the mission of allowing people to find answers never changes, I'm okay with it. I'm not jumping for joy, mind you.

Comment: @Rob I really fail to see the point of removing comments unless they should not have been made in the first place - **should I have refrained from making these comments?** 1) I do see a difference between a "dispute between users" and a misconception of one side. You **are** taking sides with any moderation action. 2) Removing may very well lead to the same conversion unfolding with another caretaker at the very point you deleted. 3) We do not even clean up constructive comments that were acted upon, do we? (except for automatically generated ones). Why bother with moderation in this case?

Comment: @Zulan We clean up constructive comments all the time. [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). They're not *meant* to stay around forever.

Comment: @Gimby many of them are duplicates, many contrived code, most useless for future SO users/visitors, the effort required by curators to handle them effectively is greater than the effort expended in asking them.   The unresearched, no-effort dumps are more abusive than the 'snarky' comments that seem to deserve a massive, and mostly self-defeating and fruitless, effort to prevent:(

Comment: How do you guys know how many comments you have?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: "They're not meant to stay around forever." Good. Last thing I need is some of the moronic garbage I've spewed over the years coming back to haunt me when I run for Emperor of Everything in a few years time.

Comment: It's not about building a library anymore. It's about being "welcoming" to specific classes of people.

Comment: Here we go again typical SO's new users "Huuu you proved me wrong, if i can't be right i'll flag you because it's rude to tell me i'am wrong huuuu", this is getting beyond stupid. OP, you've done everything you could in the most friendly manner we could ever think of. This is just yet another example of why SO's new policy is just a cancer. I repeat myself every time i see a meta post about that kind of stuff, but i'am really concerned about how SO is slowly reproducing IRL's cancerous behaviors. This is killing the 'Exchange and improve" part of SO.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There is no effective way to communicate this to users. And if SO is operating correctly, we shouldn't *need* to.

We have specific standards in place for questions. These standards help ensure that questions are reasonably scoped and genuinely answerable. But in so doing, such questions are *also* good candidates for building such a repository. Such questions are searchable by their problem statement, and they ought to produce good, actionable, focused answers. So as long as people ask questions according to the standards we lay out, we shouldn't have to tell people that their questions are part of a repository of knowledge.

The user gets the information they need, and we get the content we want. That's how the system is meant to work.

The problem is not that many users don't understand our purpose. The problem is that many users don't understand and frequently violate our *standards*. If they followed our standards, they wouldn't have to understand the purpose of those standards.

As for how we uphold that, we do as we have done. You upvote good content; you downvote bad content. You close questions that violate our standards. And so forth. SE is trying to build some tools to make it less likely for users to post bad content, which will hopefully reduce the torrent of bad questions.

Comment: Yes, the answer here is essentially try better to guarantee the input so that it requires less processing, and we're optimistic that the new wizard interface will accomplish this once we have it deployed and a few rounds of adjustments into it.

Comment: "You upvote good content; you downvote bad content. You close questions that violate our standards. And so forth." I agree, but then we're hit by the "You should leave a comment to say why you VTC / downvoted!" brigade, and then when you do, often even if it's a *constructive* comment, you're hit by the "You're making SO a really unwelcoming place!" brigade... I tend not to downvote / VTC much at all these days, extreme cases aside, for the above reasons. But I'm not sure that's the most helpful course of action either.

Comment: If the "You should leave a comment to say why you VTC / downvoted!" brigade comes by on meta, you dupeslap them so quickly they'll reconsider their stance. If they comment on Stack Overflow, you flag them no longer needed and don't comment, and go on with your day.

Comment: Hmm, so telling users “we’re not Nazis demanding standards just because we like rules, but because there’s a purpose behind these standards” is wrong?

Comment: @Holger: It's not wrong; it's just unlikely to help.

Comment: @TimPost I hope there's a lot more work done on that wizard with regards to the suggested duplicate step... and, by extension, site search.

Comment: So you expect authors to independently figure out on their own what was wrong with their post when they get a downvote or a close vote? You expect them to learn our standards and norms without guidance, when many of the norms are only documented in random, non-FAQ Meta posts? That's absurd. Most of the people who post bad content have already demonstrated (through that content) they have difficulty with this sort of independent learning/thinking. Explaining that we have goals beyond just standards on questions in isolation will help more people understand our standards and adhere to them.

Comment: @jpmc26: "*So you expect authors to independently figure out on their own what was wrong with their post when they get a downvote or a close vote?*" I don't expect them to understand what is wrong with their post when I *say what's wrong with them*. Explaining our goals will not help them since they do not care.

Answer (score 21):

SO is no longer about building a Q&A library. What's important now is making people who don't know the rules of this site, don't know how to program, don't want to put any effort into writing a good questions, don't want to learn anything feel "welcomed".

If you care about quality of content more than people's feelings prepare to get banned for a month for no reason at all and then for 3 months for a one time transgression.

I'm done with this site, maybe I will use the unpaid volunteers here once in a while to do some research for me and save me a few minutes but I'm done being one, I suggest you do the same, if enough people who are actually capable of answering questions will leave for awhile maybe there is still a chance to save SO.

Comment: reference for 20Kers: [Are we abusing our delete votes on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268071/839601) _"delete votes hanging around on controversial answers are somewhat counter-productive... In one case, the answer attracted 17 upvotes, which were slightly outweighed by 23 downvotes. Frankly, this is a bit ridiculous..."_

Comment: Folks, while Oleg's answer could be seen as lashing out, it's not attacking anyone specifically, it's just (mostly) expressing dissatisfaction with the manner that they believe we as a company are seeing things. Given that this _is_ meta, there's no profanity - I'm not going to delete it. You can down vote if you disagree with it, but deleting this means I've gotta basically delete everything else on meta that complains about people with new / low skill levels, and that's .. a lot without having a policy discussion. [1/2]

Comment: Since there's no technical reason I can agree with to remove it, _an employee_ deleting this post seems too much like removing dissension, and that's just not the kind of thing we want to do. [2/2]

Comment: @Oleg: "*If you care about quality of content more than people's feelings prepare to get banned for a month for no reason at all and then for 3 months for a one time transgression.*" It's funny; I care about the quality of content more than people's feelings. Yet I haven't been banned at all. I guess it's not about what you care about, but instead whether you're willing to violate our posting or commenting standards when you care about it. Caring should not be used as a shield from the rules.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I agree. I concur with Oleg's assessment of SO's current attitude, and I wish it could change back toward the Q&A library endeavor, but I've never been banned. So I upvoted the answer for its first paragraph. I wish Oleg just stopped there...

Answer (score 13):

Nicol's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371804/50049) communicates the gist of what I was going to say. Asking questions is *not* a shallow puddle, and folks often unwittingly fall into a pond that they weren't expecting.

We're making some changes on the front end to help people discover that there *is* a skill to asking beyond pasting code into the editor, and helping to better set people's expectations when it comes to what *we* expect. Those are the most important things, because if done correctly, we continue to build a high-quality resource even if 80% of the folks using the site simply see it as a convenient way to get answers, even if we're a little strict about quality.

But, that's not to say that we're doing great in communicating that mission, either. Stack Overflow was built, well, by programmers. Programmers aren't *always* the best folks to come up with UX copy, or notice when (to an outside perspective) stuff seems like it's been bolted on multiple times to multiple things. Our design department has always been great, but now it's even more awesome, because we have the talents of researchers and folks that have a primary focus on owning and unifying the user experience (UX).

That means, while we don't need to scream WE'RE BUILDING A HIGH QUALITY REPOSITORY OF ANSWERS TO ALL PROGRAMMING QUESTIONS until our voices echo off the moon, we can be giving users a better sense of *purpose* based on their endeavor, which will increase engagement, and the probability that any given person will stick around after hitting 250-ish rep. And yes, a sense of purpose tends to make people care quite a bit more about the fine details of something.

There's one thing about your question that particularly drew my attention, however:

> Sometimes, if a question is not clear enough to me, I refrain from answering a question even though I am almost sure that I have an answer that helps the asker.

That's good instinct to have, because I've seen great answers pull mediocre questions well above water, *especially* if the person answering (who understands the question well) actually goes back and edits the question. It's not always that you can do this, and you kinda need the OP to be responsive so you can be sure you're on the right track, but if you get a feeling in your stomach that you could nail something - it's probably worth investigating. Check for duplicates, be *sure* to engage and edit, but you might end up hitting the rep cap and getting a couple of badges for your time.

Again, these gems aren't common, but usually worth your time if you spot one. Otherwise, just leave helpful feedback and try to be friendly so the person is more likely to accept and internalize it. Even if we perfect the input to the *very best* it could possibly be, a less-than-trivial percent of questions asked are still going to lack details needed to be answered. Programmers learn by making mistakes, and a few belly-flops while trying to get help from busy volunteers is an experience that many of us have had starting out.

Comment: “That means, while we don't need to scream WE'RE BUILDING A HIGH QUALITY REPOSITORY OF ANSWERS TO ALL PROGRAMMING QUESTIONS until our voices echo off the moon” - I don’t understand. It is clear that the purpose of SO is not communicated well enough. Why not have a banner on the Ask Question page clearly stating SO’s quality expectations (preferably in bold + full caps of course)?

Comment: @Pete: "*Why not have a banner on the Ask Question page clearly stating SO’s quality expectations (preferably in bold + full caps of course)?*" Because people on the Internet are conditioned to *ignore* masthead banners at the top of pages. Thus, it will communicate with pretty much nobody. Also, you cannot "clearly" state SO's quality expectations in a paragraph.

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree that giant banners are no good. Perhaps a less spammy but unambiguous “Stack Overflow aims to create a repository of high quality Questions and Answers. [Read more]” right beneath the “Ask a Question” header? My issue is that the asker is not reminded of the purpose *at all*.

Comment: Given an unclear question, I'll sometimes edit the question into the interesting part of what they seem to be asking about, so it's worth answering.  If it turns out that wasn't what they wanted to know, they should have been clearer in the first place.  Often the boring beginner basic part of the question is taken care of by an example in the answer, or they will ask in comments.  Or they will abandon the question and we're left with a potentially-useful interesting Q&A, whether or not it helped the person that posted.

Comment: To heck with quality expectations, that's just boring trivia about long term gains that makes people zone out. It needs to be far more firmly established that Stack Overflow is for finding answers primarily. An ask question wizard is fine and dandy, but call it a Find Answer wizard and have asking a new question as the path to not finding anything existing.

Comment: And *please*, just a reminder, in your work on the wizard and Ask a Question page, pop up a big red banner and block the submission of questions that include the phrase "what's a good library" or "looking for a library" :-)))

Comment: Tim, I wonder--and I realize that this might be technically hard, confusing, or otherwise impractical, but bear with me--I wonder if it would be "worth" suppressing the visibility of answers for some duration (a day?) so that if a question is bad (eg as the one in this question is) the asker doesn't get their 'help' due to a Fast Gun, allowing the Q time to be closed (and if its closed, those suppressed answers *could* be deleted). If left open, the suppressed answers become visible as normal (further suppressing FG answers: if a better answer arrived later, it would show up at the same time).

Comment: @Draco18s that would be unfair to those having a well researched, high quality, but urgent question.

Comment: @Holger Hence my preface of "otherwise impractical." Maybe it only triggers for low-rep accounts. Maybe the time limit is only an hour.

Comment: @Holger To be fair, we don't really care about the urgency of questions in any other situation, so why care when thinking about visibility delays? See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/1863564).

Comment: @NicHartley: Yes, we don't care about urgency. But if the question is good, and the answer is good, why should we *want* to prevent the asker from seeing the answer? For *any* length of time. Not caring about urgency also means not punishing fast answers just for being fast.

Comment: @NicolBolas To discourage people from abusing the site for quick answers to questions they should have spent five minutes answering by themselves. Someone with a good question that they _can't_ answer on their own will wait an hour or two, then get an answer, and know to expect that because we'd put it in How To Ask or similar. Someone ignoring the standards with an easy-to-Google question will get frustrated at the lack of immediate satisfaction and try to find the answer in another way -- which is exactly what we want to encourage.

Comment: @NicolBolas That idea says _nothing_ about punishing fast answers, by the way. It's all about simply not showing the question for a brief period. There's no _punishment_ for somehow finding it anyway and answering, just no easy way to get there to _do_ that.

Comment: @NicHartley: I don't much care for the collateral damage from such a change. It seems far too heavy handed for something that could be handled much better in other ways. It's a feature that assumes *bad* faith, rather than good faith on the part of the asker.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't see any collateral damage, though. The only "damage" is someone who didn't bother reading How to Ask getting frustrated at the delay and seeking their answer through another means, which is, again, _exactly the point_. People who read How to Ask first will know there's a brief delay, and though they might be frustrated as well, they'll at least be able to know when the question goes public. Also, all of our anti-spam measures assume bad faith, too; we don't assume you're posting an ad for Viagra by accident. This is the same vein, just less extreme.

Comment: With that said, all this discussion would be much better on an actual Meta question about this specifically, rather than as a tangent here. I propose we agree to disagree until someone asks about implementing this :)

Comment: @NicHartley: "*Also, all of our anti-spam measures assume bad faith, too; we don't assume you're posting an ad for Viagra by accident.*" No, they require *evidence* of bad faith before acting; it doesn't stop everyone from posting links. Your suggestion is intended to affect the behavior of people who ask bad questions. But the suggestion *affects everyone*, regardless of whether they're posting bad questions or not.

Comment: @NicHartley that’s a different thing. We don’t care if the OP says, “it’s urgent”, because we don’t prioritize questions according to the questioner’s subjective urgency. Because under normal circumstances, we don’t delay answers anyway, so whether the OP says “it’s urgent” or not, they will get the answer as fast as possible. That’s why questions should not contain such noise.