# Why aren't there any more grayed-out answers?

Tags: support, status-completed, answers, design

I know that answers which have a score of -3 or less are grayed-out. But now I've been noticing some answers which are not grayed out (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089518/c-how-to-use-strtok-to-output-grades-from-input-file-find-average-minimum-an/29089779#29089779) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/29013478#29013478)) even though they have a score less than -2. This is seen on Meta as well (like [answers at the bottom of this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late?page=2&tab=votes#tab-bottom)).

I searched for the explanation on Meta Stack Overflow and found [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252529/graying-out-downvoted-answers-in-meta-discussion-questions) which says that the threshold for graying-out answers on Meta has been changed to -8 votes. But some of the heavily downvoted answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late?page=2&tab=votes#tab-bottom)(even with a score of -17) aren't grayed-out.

Why? Am I missing something? Has the graying-out feature of answers been removed from Stack Overflow and Meta.SO?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a bug apparently: [Answers with score of -3 or lower (on normal sites) and -8 or lower (on meta sites) are no longer greyed out after the series of redesigns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250852/answers-with-score-of-3-or-lower-on-normal-sites-and-8-or-lower-on-meta-sit)

Notice stating it will be fixed:
https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/site-design-update#comment4496_2374

Comment: In fact the proper link to the comment is http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/site-design-update#comment4497_2374

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah, that is true. Tho that's not an official bug track, just confirmation they know about it really.

Answer (score 14):

I have pushed a fix for this. It should fix all the sites that were affected by this. The change will be on live after our next production build.

Comment: Please answer this also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250852/answers-with-score-of-3-or-lower-on-normal-sites-and-8-or-lower-on-meta-sit