# Hiding words in questions for indexing

Tags: discussion

I've been thinking about this for a bit and this question [Why aren't there any more grayed-out answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288183/why-arent-there-any-more-grayed-out-answers?cb=1) will help make my case.

In that question the word "gray" is used several times over. If someone was about to make a similar question using "grey" to check for duplicates they might not find it.

I could expand this logic to phrases. Unfortunately a good example escapes me. The way one person would phrase something might not be the same as the next person.

Yes this would boil down to google-fu but in the case of grey vs. gray that distinction might not be so obvious and therefore be overlooked. The focus of this question is more centric to searching with SE but I suppose, if possible, applied to people using search engines as well.

Is there a way to hide keywords or phrases in posts so that it does not bloat the appearance but allow questions to be searched easier when you know it is possible to search one topic in different ways?

Something like. Understanding that my choice might be poor if this `<!--` is not indexed.

```
<!-- greyed out questions -->
```

**Edit**

I understand that google does help with synonyms but currently Stack Exchange does not which would be more important for finding dups. Not sure if google treats blank and empty as synonyms and that might be a better example.

I also didn't mean to use synonyms as my example I was more meant for this to be a SE centric question more than search engines. Regardless the answer here brings to light that even if people though my idea was useful it would be used maliciously.

Comment: A good search engine uses [*synonyms*](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonyms.html) to good effect. Leave figuring out that *grey* and *gray* are synonyms to the search engine. Google manages this, and with the new resources invested in improving Stack Exchange search I'm sure they'll tune synonym handling here too.

Comment: And duplicates for different ways to spell a concept are fine; they act as way stations to the canonical question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters gray/grey is a bad example from google stand point. People could perceive `"        "` as a blank string or an empty string. Typically in my questions I would try to use those different words anyway so as to not sound like a broken record. So I suppose if I run into that I could just change some words in peoples posts (with a proper edit explanation).

Comment: Grey... very tediously loosely related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45736/fifty-shades-of-grey

Comment: [MSE: Ignore American and British English spelling differences](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236552/167646)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, many search engines are tuned to ignore text that can't be read on the screen.

In the before time, in the long long ago, unscrupulous web designers would try to dump dictionaries into their pages to get more search hits. Eventually the search engines became aware of the scheme and started to ignore them, some search engines will even punish sites that still do it.

See: [Google's guidelines, hidden text and links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353)

Comment: Does stack exchange enforce the same guidelines as well? This malicious approach did not occur to me originally and given that fact then this whole request is a terrible idea and would be abused. Still would be neat to see synonyms supported with SE.

Comment: @Matt I'm not sure if SE has a policy for this or not, but I'm sure if it became an issue they would come up with one.