# Why fade out meta answers that have high down-vote count?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, meta

> This tag is for questions specific to down-votes, the community's way of telling peers that their content can be improved. Down-votes on meta site have different meanings.
>
> <sub>https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/down-votes</sub>

It seems that people use the down-vote button differently on meta.stackoverflow.com. While it's not a requirement for it to have a strict meaning on any given stackexchange site, the site has little control over *how* people will choose to apply it.

I therefore raise the question: Why are answers with high downvote counts are faded/muted on meta.stackoverflow.com (or any meta stackexchange site) ?

Meta is a place for discussion where everyone's voice should be treated as equal, regardless of how many people disagree with them. The effect of fading a user's meta answer takes a minority voice and makes it even quieter. This is unfair, imo.

It makes sense that answers on the non-meta sites would be faded/muted as they receive down-votes for much different reason. Namely, people do not down-vote *correct* answers simply because their personal opinions disagree with the answer author. Answers are down-voted because they are *objectively* wrong or promote a terrible habit, etc.

But that is not the case on meta. Opinions are subjective and people are using the vote button to reflect agreement/disagreement; not correctness.

I propose that the vote count alone is sufficient to represent the collective's opinion on a *meta* answer – adding CSS `opacity: 0.5;` is an unnecessarily harsh gag to users that may already have trouble finding representation in their community.

Comment: FWIW, the threshold for applying the severely downvoted css class on meta is much lower.  Like -8 or so instead of -3.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I don't believe that threshold is well-adjusted then. People use down-votes extremely loosely on meta because they are free (do not cost reputation). There is no reason to further silence unpopular opinion. Down-votes alone reflect the collective's opinion.

Comment: [Graying out downvoted answers in meta discussion questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252529/2301450)

Comment: @naomik Fading a post is *in no way* silencing you.  It's an indication that the views are strongly opposed by the community here, but they are just as accessible for anyone who is still interested in reading them.  If they were deleted just for having a differing opinion then *that* would be silencing a minority opinion.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `:hover` class restores normal opacity even on downvoted answers.

Comment: @Servy if invisible is silent, making them half as visible as the others is silencing them precisely half way. This is inarguable.

Comment: @naomik Silencing is, by definition, the *complete absence [of sound]*.  It's impossible to be "half silent".  You could say that it is quieting the voices of the minority (among other synonyms), sure, but not *silencing*.  This is inarguable.

Comment: I think the threshold of 8 works just fine, for the majority of posts. however, on wildly popular topics, it might be a bit low due to the increased traffic. would it be worth doing something about it to take care of the edge cases? I'm leaning toward not.

Comment: just an idea: maybe your own, and answers you've upvoted don't get greyed? ofc that has nothing to do with this 'issue', I just think it is a neat idea and now am thinking about it.

Comment: Have to agree with @KevinB - can we leave this off topic discussion about these alleged 'inarguable' arguments??

Comment: @KevinB what if we make the threshold a % of the views/vote on the question? That's the only way we could "reel in" wildly popular topics (short of completely removing the graying)

Comment: Patrice I like that idea, but only imposed after x views so the system still works as-is on lower traffic questions?

Comment: I'd go with: if the topic reaches x votes, the threshold jumps to y. only once, no percentages.

Comment: I'd say to come with a precise number for those threshold... we'd need a decent amount of analysis...

Comment: @rene likewise and I tend to read them closely - the effect gets my attention more

Comment: I think basing it on % of total votes on the question would be big improvement. It's reasonable to expect people to vote as freely on answers as they do on the question, so comparing answer votes vs question votes would be pretty reliable.

Comment: @Patrice If you are going to make it a % of *views*, you might as well turn it off because it is guaranteed that over time views are going to dwarf votes.

Comment: @naomik the main issue is like I just said in my previous comment: we'd need a decent amount of data digging to see how it would look and see if it makes sense.

Comment: @Louis depends on what we make the % be, but I do get your point. Back to my suggestion of linking it to the votes on the question then

Comment: @Louis I agree that post views is not a sufficient metric.

Comment: ohh good point Louis, also if the meta effect happens on main, we can call this the 'twitter effect'? linking a question off-site can influx a lot of views with little actions.

Comment: Why not just percentage of overall votes, to scale things according to participating users, as opposed to simply scaling things to the number of views, which would allow "drive-by" viewers to have a larger influence?

Comment: @meagar would we sum all the answers? would it make sense to include the question scores?

Comment: In broader terms, I don't see the need for greying out answers on meta at all, as in, I'm not sure what it is supposed to achieve. Sorting by votes and the prominently displayed vote count is enough to me to indicate that a post has met with strong disagreement. I am more interested in the original question: "**Why** fade out downvoted content", than in coming up with a new and "better" way of selecting **which** content to fade out.

Comment: @meagar with a minimum still in place, of course.  Don't want a single 0/-1 to be greyed out.

Comment: I kinda feel like there are certain cases where an answer is so incredibly off-base that i'd still want them faded to clearly show that their thought is in the minority. or deleted. like something receiving one upvote to every 10 downvotes. but that's another edge case.

Comment: @KevinB wouldn't the high down-vote count alone reflect that? Also, if the answer is significantly off-topic, rude, or offensive, it would be flagged like any other content and taken care of (deleted/edited) by moderators.

Comment: possibly replace the fade with an easier to read alternative? Similar to how deleted answers appear for 10K users in red.. Then they are clearly marked and not 'faded away' -- I do find reading the faded content a tad bit annoying (I'm aware of the hover state).

Comment: It would reflect that, yes. and the worst of them get deleted, so it's not really a problem.

Comment: @meagar You're forgetting accepted answers.  When a post is at, say, -50, and clearly strongly opposed by the community, but it is accepted, it'll be shown above every other answer.  Without a good visual indication, a casual reader may not realize immediately that the viewpoint isn't the community consensus.

Comment: @rlemon Hovering over the post removes the fading, specifically so that the fading doesn't actually inhibit your ability to physically read it.

Comment: @Servy I'm aware, but it is still slightly annoying to have to do so when reading all of the answers. Not inhibiting, just slightly annoying.

Comment: Note that you're all free to install a user stylesheet which removes the fading.

Comment: @Glorfindel so people with unpopular opinion can just see their own voices expressed equally? lol *"You can have an equal volume voice as long as you're the only one that has to hear it"*

Comment: I have also long thought the fading is out of place in a discussion-oriented space. The thoughts of the community are clear by the visible score. I think the up and down vote views here should be visible without a click, too. I also don't think the delete vote button should be available. It is frequently used to silence dissent.

Comment: @Glorfindel: I hope you don't mind, but I added that suggestion to my answer :D

Comment: Marking a question as a dupe of a 2-and-a-half year old one with [tag:status-completed] where the fix was something else than proposed here is rather unconstructive... Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: The fix was to change the fade treshold to -8. It's literally the same question. Maybe it's not the result this OP is looking for, but it _does_ answer this question.

Comment: @Cerbrus while this question is mostly about removing the threshold entirely, asking to change the threshold again is not a duplicate either. `-3` wasn't appropriate at first, so they changed it to `-8`. Maybe `-8` isn't the right number anymore and it should be `-15`, or `-50`, or never faded at all.

Comment: @ssube: The duplicate _does_ say that the current system is a result of a change to what it used to be, already. Since there are no _new_ issues raised about the fade, why should it be changed _again_?

Comment: Instead of fading out the unpopular opinion, I think an icon should pop up, representing a person who's just got mangled by a bandwagon. Or maybe a picture of Galileo Galilei getting arrested.

Answer (score 42):

Attempting to answer the question of *why* these posts are faded out is hard to separate from the question as to whether or not we *should* fade these posts out.

In very broad terms, there are two kinds of answers that wind up faded out due to downvotes:

- Answers that voice an opinion that meets with very strong disagreement from the community
- Answers that are offensive, rude, abusive or otherwise contain egregiously bad content

The first type of answers can actually be very valuable. Knowing what a community wants and what it agrees with can be just as valuable as knowing what the community *doesn't* want and has rejected. Fading these answers out actually seems counter-productive to me. In some cases they may be redundant, by which I mean it is not always necessary to have one highly voted "yes" answer and an opposite heavily downvoted "no" answer.

The second type of answer is not valuable, and they usually wind up deleted by the community or by a moderator. Fading these answers out is valuable...ish, in the window between posting and being deleted.

In both cases, I don't see a lot of value in fading the answer out, but the intent would seem to be to reduce the prominence of less useful content.

In slightly less broad terms, I think there is a grey area in faded out answers: Those that are poorly thought out, do a bad job of arguing their point, contain terrible formatting, bad arguments, etc. Due to the polarizing effect of voting on meta, these often also attract a lot of downvotes and wind up faded out. There might be some more value to fading these out, as they're generally not very useful.

Comment: *"Knowing what a community wants and what it agrees with can be just as valuable as knowing what the community doesn't want and has rejected. Fading these answers out actually seems counter-productive to me."* – you're better at words than I am, that's for sure ^_^. it'd be nice if there was an easy way to separate low-quality answers from unpopular opinion. Without relying on other user input like flags, I worry/suspect it may not be possible.

Comment: As an example of where I think this is true, is that at one point I posted [this meta-answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332306/5743988), which was downvoted considerably. I no longer agree with the opinions I posted in that answer, but at the same time I would feel it would be destructive to delete that answer, because of the loss of discussion that would occur from losing the comments. If someone ever wanted to post another answer to that question or feature request that was similar to my answer, they would see what was wrong with it from looking at the comments in my answer.

Comment: People generally perceive the fading as meaning less important, but at the same time I see strong negative opinions just as important as strong positive opinions. I almost wish there was a way to sort by absolute value.

Comment: _Answers that are offensive, rude, abusive or otherwise contain egregiously bad content_ aren't genuenly abusive answers destroyed via red flags or deleted quickly, usually?

Comment: So what happens next?

Comment: @meagar, anything?

Comment: @user633183 I'm not a Stack Overflow employee, I have no ability to do anything about this. I'd suggest making a feature request on meta if you want to see something about this feature changed, I don't personally have any stake in this and I'm not looking for any further resolution here.

Answer (score 10):

I think that its just done because thats what happens on Main Q/A as well, and there it serves the useful means of making incorrect / unclear / unhelpful content less visible. That is why the fade exists to begin with.

Thinking about it now, I'm not sure we need it for meta. Its not a massive issue, but I don't see a lot of use for the fade here. Vote sorting is already enough on meta, but at least that can be toggled by the users. The fade cannot.

**Conclusion**: I would personally have no issues with the fade being removed on meta, but I don't see a massive benefit to it either.

Answer (score 6):

I consider the fadeout effect to be for the benefit of the average passerby (let's call this person "Sam") who may not understand the voting system or pay proper attention to it. It's an extra visual cue, meaning "*be careful about using this advice... many users have expressed strong concern with the content of this post.*"

If my interpretation is correct, then it would seem to be useful on Meta as well. The goal would be to tell Sam, visiting the question months or years later, "*be careful about following this advice... it may not reflect the general opinion of the community.*"

The fadeout doesn't mean that there's nothing valuable in the post... that's what "delete" means. An enthusiast, either in some technology or in SO administration, may still find valuable content in the post. It's worth keeping around and the "idea seedlings" could eventually pop up in future posts, but the fadeout is still valuable to Sam who doesn't understand or pay attention to the post score.

Comment: And as Rene answered: The treshold for the fade is at -8, so it isn't applied as a result of merely 3 users disliking it.

Comment: Agreed, although the exact threshold is pretty arbitrary. We could make it bigger or smaller - point is that the fadeout effect still has some value for its target audience... users who are less familiar with SO and come here just looking for advice, not to participate in the discussion.

Answer (score -7):

While we're at it, let's remove the answers sorting based on vote count.

Your argument against this fading is that lower voted answers are less visible.
I'd argue that the vote count sort is just as effective in making downvoted answers less visible. I mean, who reads through a meta thread with 10 answers? **cough**.
Sillyness aside, lower sorted answers are viewed less than higher sorted ones. The fact a lower *voted* answer is faded out is easily avoided by simply hovering over the answer. On the other hand, there is no way to sort the lowest voted answer to the top.

*If* we're going to remove the fade based on answer visibility, we need to remove sorting by vote as well, because I can guarantee you that that will be the next [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

## That, I do *not* support.

If you *really* don't like the fade, there's a good [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334468/why-fade-out-meta-answers-that-have-high-down-vote-count/334500#comment394812_334468) by [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel):

> *"Note that you're all free to install a user stylesheet which removes the fading."*

Here's the style:

```
.downvoted-answer .post-text,
.downvoted-answer .post-signature,
.downvoted-answer .comments,
.downvoted-answer .vote>*{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

That way, answers can look like *you* want them to, while SO doesn't have to change anything (and deal with the inevitable *"omg something changed!"* backlash).

Comment: _I mean, who reads through a meta thread with 10 answers?_ Ehm, *nervously raises hand*

Comment: *"If we're going to remove the fade based on answer visibility, we need to remove sorting by vote as well, because I can guarantee you that that will be the next feature request"* – this is slippery slope fallacy. Removing the sensible default sorting should not preclude affecting a change on the answer fade.

Comment: @Cerbrus user stylesheets don't solve the issue I've presented. About 0% of people will install the custom sheet you have proposed. The idea here is that all answers, despite how unpopular they may be, should have an equal opacity to other answers. This gives everyone an equal voice. Down-votes enough are enough to signal to readers that a particular answer may be unpopular or highly disagreed with.

Comment: @naomik: The sorting removes the "equal voice" answers have. Like I said, _only_ removing the fade isn't enough if you want all answer to _truly_ be equally visible.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's unreasonable to expect all the answers to be displayed simultaneously – there is a physical limitation of screen space. Choosing an *order* to display the posts is an entirely separate topic, and less important as it's already a user-controlled UI element.  I know you're being purposefully argumentative tho, so I'm not sure why I'm wasting my time.

Comment: *"Like I said, only removing the fade isn't enough if you want all answer to truly be equally visible"* – if you mean to suggest that unless we can achieve 100% true equality then we should not even bother, I disagree with you whole-heartedly. Especially if the reason for inaction is so SO doesn't have to *"deal with the inevitable 'omg something changed!' backlash"*

Comment: I'm saying the sorting should be randomized to achieve true equality. Which is never going to happen.

Comment: That said, please stop with the accusations, they're not constructive. I gave my answer, you disagree. That's fine.

Comment: If you're truly intending to be constructive with me right now, please try to stay on topic. Identifying false barriers to my request like changing the default sorting – something which is very firmly established and has likely had many discussions/refinements about how it should be implemented – only serve to obstruct my actual issue.

Comment: I'm not just answering you. I'm voicing my opinion on this feature request for all readers. The sorting is a concern that comes up when you want to improve a downvoted answer's visibility. A concern many users might not realize, so I consider it a valuable addition to the answer.

Comment: And anyway you could not possibly argue for post visibility equality and suggest Glorfindel's solution is actually a good one.

Comment: I'm not arguing _"for increased post visibility"_, in the first place. I'm saying we ___shouldn't___ change it, and offering an alternative for users that just don't like the fade.

Comment: No need for random sorting. There is "oldest" sorting, which achieves something like equality - answers are sorted regardless of content.

Comment: @anatolyg: Then you're promoting [FGITW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite) behavior. My point is that there's no point in this request.

Comment: I considered posting this as an answer but I didn't because I thought it could easily be seen as trolling and that would blur the discussion at hand. It looks like we need two votes. One for the facts and one for the feelings.

Comment: @rene: Funnily enough, the only person trying to refute my answer started off by calling some lines in there fallacies, and was accusing me of being biased against herself.

Comment: @rene I don't read this answer as trolling, but I do read it as "your request is ridiculous, so here is a ridiculous response". YMMV.

Comment: @Stijn: What can I say, I'm Dutch, I'd rather be blunt & honest.

Comment: @stijn it looks like we ended up in a definition issue on trolling. Let's head to ELU.se ...

Comment: @Cerbrus *"Funnily enough, the only person trying to refute my answer started off by calling some lines in there fallacies ..."* – what, are you going to suggest you spoke without logical fallacy? Your argument is so textbook slippery slope fallacy that you could use it as an example in a debate lesson.

Comment: @naomik: Yea, take that out of context. That works.

Answer (score -12):

I really don't see why we would need to change the behavior of fading answers that drop below a score of -8.

There is no fair / un-fair in voting. A user analyzed the question and decided to post an answer. It might be their own opinion or one that wasn't yet brought up in the discussion. The voting then reflects how the meta-crowd agrees or disagrees with it.

It is important that such (contra) opinions are posted and it is also important that everybody quickly sees that an answer doesn't have much community support, specially when some meta visitors only vote in a split second. Having them first to read all that stuff would hurt vote-ability.

Posts don't have feelings, so it can't be a harsh gag if they have trouble this time to represent the opinion of the community. They slowly fade to the background and wait for a better moment in time ...

Comment: The issue isn't hurt feelings, but rather the (perceived?) suppression of dissenting opinions. Not sure where I fall on this particular UI issue yet, but I do think that Meta should try to avoid the echo chamber effect.

Comment: Users post opinion in meta and their posts can sometimes be representative of their feelings. So sure, posts don't have feelings but the users that post them do. Making a well-written response 50% as visible as another one just because people disagree with it is about the same thing a toddler sticking their fingers in their ears and saying "lahlahlah I cannot hear you!!" – of course if the content of the answer were poorly written, rude, or offensive, then it should be flagged and moderated/edited/deleted accordingly.

Comment: the suppression of dissenting opinions is only perceived that way by the poster. Why do I have to be made equally aware of all those opinions @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, if it is interesting enough I'll read everything and a single hover will unfade stuff for me. Most topics I really can't be bothered if I know the community consensus it is good enough for me.

Comment: @naomik are you comparing me with a toddler? You're rude. I don't think meta is meant to reach consensus, because it seems you're after that. It simply is a somewhat democratic majority vote. Don't try to win over my vote by claiming you didn't get enough attention. You got equal attention but the way it was written down or the points brought up didn't get the traction you would have hoped for. That is a shame because sometimes we loose good proposals that way but it is how meta works now and I personally don't see any other system that wouldn't have more down sites.

Comment: @rene *"Making a well-written response 50% as visible as another one ..."* – are you the one making the well-written-but-unpopular posts appear with 50% opacity? If not, then I'm making no such comparison to you... I'm talking about the CSS styling choice personified as a belligerent toddler that's unwilling to hear/see opinions that differ from his/her own.

Comment: @naomik yes I do make such posts ... thanks for checking.

Comment: @rene I'm not asking if you make posts. I was (rhetorically) asking if you're the one making the grey/faded styling choice ... which I assume you're not. So you can rest assured I did not personally attack you and compare you to a baby. If you think I'm rude for calling out the CSS styling choice, then so be it.

Comment: @naomik fair enough. And you're free to call out any styling aspect on the site and I'm here to defend all the blurs ...

Comment: I don't think the fading per se silences anyone, it's just annoying to readers. It's an imposition for the sake of imposition, for the sake of convention because it's done on the regular stacks. It serves no real purpose other than making the end user do a meaningless task just to read. IMO delete votes on Meta are more used to silence dissent than the fading.

Comment: @ChrisBaker: When delete votes are used to silence dissent, I undelete-vote. However, often delete votes are mistaken as an attempt to silence dissent, while said dissent was nothing but an unconstructive / incoherent rant, which was deleted for it's (lack of), well, value to the site.

Comment: @ChrisBaker you have > 10K, you can see deleted answers. Maybe find some posts that back your statement. It might happen but I don't think that  it occurs on a regular basis.

Comment: I kinda want this answer to sit on 8 downvotes. Appeals to my sense of humour ;)

Comment: @Yvette we still hat fun here ...

Comment: @rene just because I can see them doesn't change the social aspect of having other people vote to **delete** your **opinion** because they don't like it. The posts that "back my statement" are any non-spam post on meta that is delete-voted. The fading, as I said, is just an annoyance to the reader, it's a CSS effect. The OP sees the downvote, message sent, the fading is a side-effect. Whereas a delete vote (on Meta) is someone saying that downvoting is not enough, I want to make your post go away.

Comment: @ChrisBaker: again, the assumption that delete-votes are used to express disagreement. Deleted answers are usually just extremely low quality: rants, accusations, that kind of content.

Comment: "low quality" is a label someone might apply to an *opinion* if they subjectively don't like it. Delete votes are a site mechanic designed to clean up "low quality" posts in a different space that is *not* opinion-oriented and where quality has a far more objective definition. I've been around long enough that you aren't going to gaslight me into believing I have not seen what I've seen over the years. It isn't a *major* problem (why I didn't start a meta post about it) I just mentioned it in the context of this discussion about opacity. With that, this is getting off-topic, let's leave off.

Comment: @ChrisBaker it is certainly a concern and [Shog9 took some action](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268071/578411) a couple of years ago. Maybe it is time to evaluate if that unwanted behavior of using delete votes for a different goal has grown since then.

Comment: @ChrisBaker [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/539463/unpopular-meta-posts-that-were-deleted-and-then-undeleted) are some concrete examples, in case you want to continue this discussion in another post. It's hard to find more since SEDE doesn't show deleted posts.

Answer (score -13):

Because developers are, and should be, lazy.

Negative votes result in fade out on the main site(s) for clear and good reasons.

Meta runs on the same engine.  Without a clear and compelling reason, it behaves like the main site does.

Now, that was almost certainly the original reason.  The reason now?  Probably inertia.  People justify existing systems as being just through random ways.

Now, inertia is often a good position in a working system, because changes in working systems have a small chance of making the system not work.

Comment: I'd say that you're correct, except that in this case you aren't. The SO team took the time and effort to [make the threshold -8](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252614/211627). At that time, nothing stopped them from making the threshold -999. Clearly the SO team actually *wants* the fadeout.

Comment: @JDB That is covered in paragraph 4 and 5?  The claimed reasons are noise, in my opinion.  It exists because it existed for free (due to meta being a clone of main), and then the principle of design inertia guarantees that random reasons to keep it will be generated.  The exact reasons given why aren't the *actual* reason why: debunk them and more appear.  The actual reason is that reasons justifying the current state are generated in any situation like that.  Pargraph 5 states why, despite the irrelevance of the justifications, following them is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: So you think that because there's a fadeout effect on the main site, the SO team, due to inertia, justified the same effect on meta, albeit with a higher threshold, without any other prevailing thought or theory? I guess that could be true... but it could be equally true that they actually have a thoughtful reason.

Comment: @JDB I'm sure they had a thought or theory.  But the *cause* of that thought or theory was "it was already there, can I justify it?" The exact details of that thought or theory could change without a change in behavior. Debunk one particular theory or thought, and another appears. People come up with reasons why "what is there is right", and the exact details of the reasons they invent have little to do with "what is there staying there". The arguments generated for it from design inertia wouldn't be sufficient to make it be added if it was not there.

Comment: it's a convenient theory because it can never be proven wrong.

Comment: @JDB Evidence can be provided for or against it.  It makes predictions.  It generates a model of design changes that can be determined to be useful or not.  It isn't *easy* to prove right or wrong, but few things are.

Comment: I think it's a shame that this answer is fade out. It contains some interesting stuff.