# Can we ask programming competition like question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

While reviewing the reopen votes, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468354/fair-division-of-a-kingdom). Here OP ask question of programming competition. They mention in question that there is no matter of programming language.

This question is already closed, but get 21 up-votes and already voted cast for reopen.

As per my knowledge I vote to leave closed. Is this OK?

Can I or anyone ask this type of question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It's not closed because it is about a task from a programming competition, but because it's too broad - OP presents a complete assignment and then says "I don't want code, I want ideas" but that's neither specific nor useful as it just leads to a bikeshed question where everybody wants to post their own idea as an answer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278771/how-to-deal-if-the-user-asks-for-code-in-online-programming-competition

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should be (and stay) closed. It is far too broad for SO's format.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, there's nothing wrong with [asking about an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

While the question may *read* too broad at first blush, there are some distinctions that make it appear at least salvageable if not on topic to me:

- The question itself is clear and concise about what it needed for it to be answered successfully - code isn't necessary, but an algorithmic approach and description are what it's looking for.
- The OP has an assumption about the data already (regardless of how correct they may be), and this should be factored in to whether or not something like this is too broad.
- Look at the *answers* it got.  There are some very detailed and thorough answers to approaches on how to solve this question.

I would personally not want to close this question, but it's easy enough to have that knee-jerk reaction.  This particular case requires a bit of patience to it.

As for your other question:  you most certainly can write questions about algorithms, but they have to still be on topic and fall in the same rules as any other question on the site.