# What about questions seeking help for coding challenges?

Tags: discussion, scope

From time to time I see questions that ask for help in coding challenges. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870749/any-better-way-of-writing-this-function-in-python-for-determining-if-a-string-is) is an example. I don’t know if this kind of questions should be allowed on Stack Overflow, because to me it feels like helping the person to cheat in the challenge, which is like doing someone else's homework. What to do with such questions?

Comment: Handle them like any other question.

Comment: Is helping me solve a coding problem I'm stuck on at work help me "cheat at work"?

Comment: Related: should I do someone else's homework? [Mrs Johnson disagrees](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41871158/2564301).

Comment: @deceze When you then pretend that you did it alone and that's all your work: yes. But the other question is: who is not cheating on such "challenges". I assume the most of them do.

Comment: "Asking for help for homework is clearly stated as being off-topic" is not true ...

Comment: *"Asking for help for homework is clearly stated as being off-topic"*: Not really ... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Tom Can *you* (potential Stack Overflow answerer) judge that? Where does "research to solve a problem" end and "cheating" start? Under what circumstances *may* I ask a question without it being "cheating" of some sort?

Comment: I specify: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." So, I'll use this as a guideline.

Comment: @deceze If you can't answer a challenge without help from others, then don't participate in that challenge. Challenges are supposed to test your skill and knowledge compared to other participants and not "who asked first on SO". But again, I don't think that many other people care about that, that's why these challenges are quite useless (at least in my opinion).

Comment: @Tom If there's a restriction on the challenge à la *"may not use the internet or any external resource other than your own head"*, then yes, that's cheating. But no developer works without constantly looking stuff up, so, yes, I agree that that's unrealistic and rather useless.

Comment: see also: [Is there a need for a new flag type: 'Embargoed until contest closes at <date/time>'?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252676/is-there-a-need-for-a-new-flag-type-embargoed-until-contest-closes-at-date-ti)

Comment: @deceze Looking something up is something different than asking someone else for help. Everyone can read the same resources available on the internet, but not everyone can access the same persons to ask them for help. This is way I would discourage that for challenges.

Comment: @Tom Sure, there's a distinction there. But again, there's a spectrum from "researching a detail" (may involve asking someone, depending on your arbitrarily decided "rules") to "having someone else complete the entire task". There's no way we can make a judgement on where one ends and the other starts, besides our own definition of "too broad" questions we categorically don't answer, regardless of the context they were asked in.

Comment: @deceze Well, I should note that I'm not discussing if such questions are off-topic or not. I agree with Martijns answer since SO has it's rules which generally allow such questions. I'm just arguing that in my own opinion these challenge participants shouldn't get help from others, but that only means that I won't answer such questions on SO. I can't ban/forbid them ... (not yet *har har*).

Comment: @Tom Personally I hardly care where a question originated from, if it's a *good question* which would educate everyone, then I'm not going to not answer it because I suspect it is being asked in the context of some coding challenge. Having said that, I think it's unlikely that questions which can rather clearly be traced back to a challenge will be *good questions*; more often than not they're poor to begin with. Good challenge questions probably won't appear as such. So this seems like a problem that mostly solves itself in practice.

Comment: If you know what contest question is coming from it usually makes it easier to downvote (as in most cases there are plenty of existing solutions around) and vote to close (as you have better search terms to find SO answer). Otherwise indeed there is not much difference from any other questions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You treat such questions like any other question.

It doesn't matter what the motivations are for asking a question. A good question is a good question, a bad question is a bad question, regardless of where the underlying problem originates from. If the question and its answers are useful to future visitors, it can stay. We are here for the long tail, after all.

The Stack Overflow community can't be tasked with enforcing third-party restrictions. That's up to the third-party here, like the competition organisers. If the answers to such a question are used to break competition rules, that is a choice the question asker has to make, and up to the designated judges or referees of the competition to police.