# How to improve a long-standing Q&A that has accumulated general answers which may be useful to others but aren't actually answering the question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Codility passing car - how to approach this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774985/codility-passing-car)

This question appears to ask about how to interpret a coding test question, but most of the answers are just posts of answers to the test. My feeling is that many of the answers should be deleted. I've downvoted a number of them and left a comment. However, due to the age of the question, I don't know the best to help fix this.

Comment: Ugh, and answers in every language, too. Yes, most of those probably need to be deleted. Might be able to keep some of them by broadening the question to ask more generally about the solution to the problem, but keep the *specific* question that was asked so as not to invalidate the answer that actually answers that?

Comment: If the question were broadened such that answers in those many languages would be considered answers to the question, I think the question would then be the textbook definition of Too Broad

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't need to be a repository of solutions to online programming challenges. There are plenty of other sites for those.

Comment: If the lack of existence of other sites to ask a question doesn't justify the question being asked on Stack Overflow, then the existence of other sites to ask a question doesn't justify the question being off-topic or unsuitable for Stack Overflow, @kaya3. Specific, answerable questions about a particular programming challenge are perfectly suitable for Stack Overflow, and, in fact, welcome. The primary thing that goes wrong is people posting answers in every language under the sun. That's correctable with a language tag and a delete button.

Comment: @CodyGray What I mean is that Stack Overflow doesn't need Q&As where the answers are a pile of everyone's solutions to the same problem, code-only. Questions which explicitly just said "here's a Codility challenge, please post your code for it" would blatantly be off-topic, and the same logic says that even if a question doesn't just ask for that, if its answer section is full of answers written *as if* the question asks that, those answers aren't any more fit for Stack Overflow than they would be if the question *did* ask for those kinds of answers.

Comment: I don't propose that the existence of other sites where people do post code-only solutions to such challenges is a reason that they shouldn't be accepted here, only that the existence of those sites means that rejecting such answers here does not make the internet less useful for people who do want to search for them.

Comment: Programming challenges rarely are _practical_ unique to software development questions.

Comment: Man, that title could definitely use some work though; it doesn't even attempt to describe the actual problem.

Comment: Ironically, the title of this question identifies a genuine problem, but I was disappointed to see that the content of the question is specific to coding challenges. It's tempting to answer this post in a way that'd be useful to others but isn't actually answering the question. The problem is just that: question title is popular and attracts lots of clicks, question is different and gets an answer that technically resolves it but doesn't help the folks pouring in from search, so other answers show up that don't technically answer the question but are on-spot for the searchers and get upvotes.

Answer (score 9):

Let's separate the two questions

**This is about a coding challenge**

And [questions like that are not off-topic on their own](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342285/2370483)

> It doesn't matter what the motivations are for asking a question. A good question is a good question, a bad question is a bad question, regardless of where the underlying problem originates from. If the question and its answers are useful to future visitors, it can stay. We are here for the long tail, after all.

**What to do with the answers?**

Apparently the original question was about Java (I can't see Martjin adding that tag on a whim), but the original link is dead and there's no Archive link so there's no way to be 100% sure. Since most of the other answers read as "Me too in [some other language here]", I trimmed most of them out. I left two groups of answers in

1. Attempting to answer in Java
2. Attempting to explain the problem being asked about, even if they used a different language

In most cases, a simple mod flag on these won't suffice. They look too much like "incorrect answer" flags (good chance you get a decline). A Meta post explains in better detail.

Comment: To paraphrase Brad: This question just isn't a good question to begin with, so it should be closed and removed because of that.