# Questions from Active Contests

Tags: discussion, moderation

Is it acceptable to ask questions from on going programming contests. If we encounter such questions should it be down voted and flagged for moderator?

Comment: Related: [Comments that a problem is part of a live contest get removed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252013/247702)

Comment: You can downvote using whatever criteria you want (as long as it's not user-targeting).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple answer is "no" you shouldn't down-vote and/or flag simply because it's a question from an contest. The normal rules over questions still apply.

It's not up to us to police programming contest, interview or academic coursework questions.

If you know that it's such a question then perhaps leave a comment - but be polite and expect the comment to be removed - but otherwise do nothing.

By all means raise it with the contest organisers who can then contact SE about the question if they want it taken down.

Comment: so in such a scenario is it wrong to flag it to be closed ?

Comment: @sasha - Yes. It's up to the contest organisers to ask SE directly for the question to be removed. It's not a job for the moderators.