# Are questions related to UVa Online Judge considered off-topic?

Tags: support, scope

Is asking to find a bug for a code written to solve a [UVa](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/) considered off topic on SO?

At first I was thinking about code review, but the site help center mentions that the site is for "smelly code" which is bug-free but could be improved.

So is SO the right place for such questions?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258295/questions-from-active-contests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the rules for UVa Online Judge allow you to have such help from other parties, it should be OK.

If I understand your question right, you have written code to solve a challenge, and there is a bug in the code you wrote yourself. Asking for help solving your bug is a fair use of Stack Overflow, assuming of course that you have tried to solve your problem yourself first. And assuming, of course, that the rules of the contest allow you such help from third parties.

Comment: My questions would be about challenges I am doing as an exercise and not as a part of an on-going contest.
some people ask about on-going challanges and I found it pretty irretating and not fair.
+1 for the ehtihcs :)

Comment: The rules of an external site are irrelevant. We're not here to enforce their terms.

Comment: @Wooble Fair point. But we're also not here to help people to cheat.

Comment: @S.L.Barth It's impractical to have any rules about this, because people could just not explain the association with the contest. The question may also be useful in other contexts unrelated to the context. Answerers are certainly feel free to abstain if they don't like a question for whatever reason, but the consensus has been against requiring any enforcement of external policies. Whether contest rules or legally-binding NDAs, it's an issue to be sorted out between the asker and the organization.