# Are UVa Online Judge Runtime Errors off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I ran into one of these in the close queue and wasn't sure what to do with it. [Assuming there's no ethical problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258473/2069350) with answering [UVa Online Judge](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/) debugging questions, I have a more specific question regarding questions asking for debugging help for Runtime Errors.

Per the Judge's [verdict information](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=16&Itemid=31), "The exact cause [of a Runtime Error] is not reported to the user". This fact results in questions where someone pastes their code, and asks "why did it fail? It works on my machine!". Such questions appear to run afoul of the "no SSCCE" close reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help... must include... **a specific problem or error**...

However, the asker is generally unable to provide the stack trace (or even an exact error type), since UVa won't. The asker often can't even reproduce the error. If the stack trace were available, the questions would often be on-topic. I feel bad in these cases saying "sorry; you didn't tell us the unknown problem, so you're on your own!"

On the other hand, "I know it's wrong but I don't know how or why" is clearly off-topic, and no one wants to dig through code to find an unknown error (which might end up being something inane like "doesn't exit with code 0"!).

So, **what should be done with this sort of question?**

---

**Example:** This question has a couple of downvotes and is in the close queue, but would be a reasonably well-formed question (could use clearer expected input/output) if only the asker knew what the error message was!

[image: Question 25652693]

Comment: Not per se IMHO, but usually the OP's don't show any effort to debug that kinda stuff themselves seriously.

Comment: One point is that these online judge sites count as external resources for SO, and usually I don't accept links to the problem statements/tasks as proper description for expected input/output and performance restrictions.

Comment: UB might well be a reason why running on the online judge site fails. Different toolchains may behave differently on this behalf. Though this should be detectable for the OP by investing some effort on keeping an eye on compiler warnings and such.

Answer (score 6):

I've seen a lot of these recently, pertaining to challenges on UVa and similar sites, and I usually vote to close without feeling bad.

The only difference between these questions and the ones we routinely close for "no SSCCE" is that in these questions the OP has not only neglected to reduce the problem to a minimal reproduction of the error, but has not even done enough testing to produce the error in the first place. (Remember the economics; we are trying to discourage questions that make every would-be respondent do work that the petitioner could have done *once*.)

These are not earnest novice coders being denied vital information by unhelpful robots and coming to us for help; they are lazy (not in a good way) novice coders choosing to take part in challenges which *require* coding to a high standard, then finding that that's too much like work and copy-paste-posting here as an easy shortcut.

Comment: So, what should be done with this sort of question?

Comment: @anatolyg: I advise you to use your own judgement. If you think that the question would be of use to future developers (not just future contestants), and that the OP has done adequate work, by all means leave it up, and answer if you like; otherwise close.