# Should we answer a question while OP is midst an online test?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

This is the first time I across such a scenario where [OP is midst an online test, and posted a question to a quick answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886181/group-by-and-count-in-oracle). The question is too basic, however, the concerning thing is this statement:

> Please help am midst of some online test. Thank you

I didn't notice it until I read that last line after posting an answer. Usually I don't pay much attention to "*Please help me..Thanks..*" etc. But this is special. Isn't this an abuse of the site?

I agree, OP could have done a search and might have found a ready made answer, but then it would still be fine to an extent as it needs minimum understanding to search and find an answer.

I removed my answer and I have voted to close the question, which I am not sure is the correct thing to do. OP has not shown his attempt. The question is too basic, however, we do answer basic questions now and then. However, my question addresses a bigger concern than these.

Comment: Does this answer your question [How to deal if the user asks for code in online programming competition?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278771/how-to-deal-if-the-user-asks-for-code-in-online-programming-competition)

Comment: Not exactly, somewhat close though. In this case, OP posted most probably copy/paste from an online test, and expecting a quick answer to proceed in the test with a ready made answer. No attempt to show us.

Comment: The "lack of attempt" is not a close reason, nor is the "cheating". Although one or both are usually signals that there are other problems that can justify closing the question.  In general, answering questions should be about the question, not the source.  If you think it is a useful question (to the wider programming community, not just people taking the test), then answer it, it shouldn't matter than it is from a test or homework or anything.  If it isn't useful, then downvote, (vote to close if there is an applicable reason) and move on.

Comment: @psubsee2003 YEs, that's what I did. Downvote, vote-to-close. But was not confirm about the reason to close, so discussing at meta. Seems I did the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

You did the right thing by removing your answer and voting to close the question. However I would have chosen a different off-topic reason. Quality of a question should be the first priority in deciding about a close vote, instead of being concerned if the OP is in the middle of an exam or contest.

That particular question is asking for help without a clear problem statement a without a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. It is not useful to other readers and future visitors in its current form, so it should get closed anyways. You may leave a polite comment informing the OP that its not appropriate to ask such questions.

As [ChrisF♦ mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258297/):

> The simple answer is "no" you shouldn't down-vote and/or flag simply because it's a question from an contest. The normal rules over questions still apply.
>
> It's not up to us to police programming contest, interview or academic coursework questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If OP is midst a contest, he would not have that much time to word the question appropriately. And since he wants to seek an answer to cheat the exam, he wouldn't have anything to show what he has tried so far. So,the basic laws still apply. But, if we encourage such questions, the quality would be compromised. I think this is a case where both reasons fit to vote-to-close rule, quality and cheating.

Comment: @LalitKumarB yup, basic laws still apply.