# Very Very Bad Question About an Exam... How to be polite to bad faith people

Tags: discussion, welcoming

I read Jay Hanlon's blog post and I understand we should try to be nice to new users. I try to be nice to people in general. But this question: [Can you help me with my python program assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140343/can-you-help-me-with-my-python-program-assignment) is honestly just a really bad faith effort all around. I read a lot of the responses to the blog but in my mind questions like this are the reason people on this site have gotten jaded. How are we going to differentiate from the community being "too mean" versus new users acting in bad faith?

Comment: It's so bad that my first guess would be 'troll'.

Comment: @MartinJames:  I work for higher education and it's coming up on finals' week, so this seems to be at least timely.

Comment: @Makoto ugh..  TBH, I would prefer it to be a troll, at least then I could better rationalize the horror of it:(

Comment: @MartinJames:  You mean...you *can't* rationalize the horror that students would *actually* attempt to cheat on their final exam?  I suppose I'm numb to it by now, since I've seen it attempted in many forms before...

Comment: Jeez, and I thought [**my cheater**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366999/2191572) was ballsy.

Comment: @Makoto no - it's just the embarrassingly brazen attempt to do it, and the insulting assumption that SO professionals/enthusiasts would be happy to help:(

Comment: @Makoto actually, thanks for the 'finals' week' warning: I will be extra-viligant so as try and not help some students dis those who, well, actually know stuff.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's so bad that, if others had not deleted it, I would have broken my own 'no meta effect' rule and delved it myself.

Comment: I wish I was a 10K user just so I could explore the seedy underbelly of SO.

Comment: Its not so much that we should be more nice, its more that the site in general should appear nicer, to everyone.

Comment: You could always link to [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and leave it at that.

Comment: @EJoshuaS it wasn't that I didn't know how to do that. I know about those it's just that there was a whole blog post about being more polite and I just wanted to know what Jay among others want the community to do in such cases of such bad faith

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was marked as _spam or rude or abusive_, that seems a bit of an overreaction.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would contend that this abuses the good intentions of the community though admittedly not abusive in the other sense of the term

Comment: @fordprefect That is not what abuse means in the specific meaning applied when content is hidden for reasons of _spam or rude or abusive_. Assigning that meaning leads to overloading the term abuse, and, I think, should very well be considered a form of hostility from the community to new users not following the rules.

Comment: Wow. But the worst I ever saw was on SE.mathematics. The body of the question was a slightly blurry skewed phone photo of the exam paper, complete with the student's name, with virtually no text apart from the title, which identified the number of the question he wanted answered.

Comment: @MartinJames Well, two can play at that game. "The best thing to do while writing Python is to freely mix tab and space characters for indentation. Use tabs one line, and spaces the next. Really helps to spice things up."

Comment: @CharlesSrstka lol. Imma so tempted, on occasion.  I would do it if I could be sure it would not mislead some other users:)

Answer (score 73):

As Makoto notes... This question was probably beyond help. Even if someone was in the mood for a heroic edit, the author was trying to get an answer on a deadline, for a purpose which... wasn't exactly what you'd call *ethical*.

So here's how we can be polite: get rid of it before the author gets themselves into even more trouble, the less said the better.

[image: a diagram of the question and comments with "not needed" scrawled on the comments]

That last comment was pretty ok, but... I still wouldn't really recommend it; not because it isn't polite, but simply because in this case the question is so far beyond help that anything you might say stands the chance of backfiring in unexpected ways. It is wise to talk *very carefully* to desperate people, if you must talk to them at all.

Comment: "anything you might say stands the chance of backfiring in unexpected ways" There was a comment on one of the other threads alleging that "guys" seem to like doing that sort of thing on purpose. Other than the singling out of "guys", I get the feeling that this is true of a good many people.

Comment: I'm afraid that the red freehand circle is cancelled out by the green ones, so no bonus vote for you.

Comment: It's ---extremely sad--- funny. We instruct SO people to stop behaving like they do because we expect bad treatment from outer people when we do, whereas these outer people are trying to make us stop telling them to expect bad treatment when they post bad content. Basically, we're not getting rid of the unwelcoming atmosphere of "if you do this expect backlash", we're just moving it towards other people.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I've given up.  I'm no longer posting any comments, at all, to any posts from the '<50 reps'.  s/comment/target

Comment: I don't know about you, @Félix... But I was getting nasty personal emails from desperate folk I'd tried to help years ago, long before I worked here, long before these "toxic" meme ever took root. [New users can be like injured animals](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/822558225639809024); you gotta expect them to snap, and approach accordingly.

Comment: Now, what the STC means?

Comment: It stands for "Shocks The Conscience", @Braiam. I'll leave its functionality to your imagination.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, I should indeed try seeing it like that. The image makes it more acceptable than the current "these people that mostly want to insult me" vibe I feel.

Comment: Would this not result in the user getting offended that their question was downvoted and deleted without explanation? I see no way to respond properly to this question that does not risk offending the user. As least with someone *mentioning* their unethical behavior, perhaps they'll learn that people *really do* care about them cheating and will be dissuaded in the future. I applaud the commenters for just not cussing the person out, to be honest (although I suppose there might be deleted comments I can't see). The only one that *maybe* crosses the line a *little* is the "instant F" one.

Comment: We get *TONS* of questions like this, @jpmc26. Schools keep letting more kids into classes, not teaching them, and then expecting them to do stuff on finals week... and so every finals week, we get a bunch of desperate students looking for help here. Some of them do it right; lots of them don't. Regardless of what we do in response, next time finals rolls around there's gonna be a fresh crop.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm honestly confused by your response; I feel there has been some misunderstanding. I didn't assert we don't get many of these or that responding would reduce the number we get or that we shouldn't help those who act ethically. I said that *any* form of rejecting the question (including downvotes, closure, and deletion) risks offending the asker and that *maybe*, just once in a while, telling people that cheating is bad might make them reconsider.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but I feel that somebody trying to cheat on an exam _ought to_ get into even more trouble.

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks; the images are very clear and explicit. But, without comments how the OP learn what is wrong with the question? I always thought down-voter/close-voter should leave the comment explaining why. Chances are that, OP will ask similar question again and it just increases the cleanup work. I agree that the comment must be polite though.

Comment: Related on Information Security: [Is image blurring an unsafe method to obfuscate information in images?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129683/is-image-blurring-an-unsafe-method-to-obfuscate-information-in-images)

Comment: Could you explain why this questions is now marked _spam or rude or abusive_? That seems a bit of an overreaction, as it is none of those things.

Comment: Because there was a rude/abusive flag on the post which was automatically validated when the post was deleted, @Mark. I've cleared that and re-deleted it to avoid confusion since *this* discussion is getting a lot more traction than I expected.

Comment: If you want to educate folks one-on-one about cheating, that's your prerogative @jpmc26. But I can't demand it or even recommend it in this context, nor would I expect it to do much good in most cases.

Comment: There's a handy "how to ask" page [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the close reason itself @Amit. Lots of people do click through and read it. Whether this particular asker would is unknown, but it isn't as though there's no helpful information available to them. Also, if they tried to ask again within a day they'd be blocked with a message full of other useful tips for asking good questions.

Comment: "get rid of it before the author gets themselves into even more trouble, the less said the better."  Disagree.  Personally, I would like to see these left visible so perhaps their school might find them and they can rain down their furious vengeance on the cheater.

Comment: @Shog9  Please consider an alternative explanation to how schools teach students... perhaps "Schools keep letting more kids into classes, trying their best at first to teach them, finally realizing that their attitudes and work ethic are lacking, so decide to at least hold them accountable and show them what the real world expects, so they give them the final as they should know it instead of dumbing it down just because the students refused to learn.  Then students panic and expect to cheat their way out of a jam."  We should allow any comments that discourage this behavior.

Comment: Behind each of these students is an incredible amount of social and economic pressure, @cperkins. You might as well stand in the spillway of the grand coulee dam and scream at the water to reverse course.

Answer (score 40):

*What* we moderate on hasn't changed.  That sort of question is *still* unsuitable for the site, no matter how nice or mean we are to them.

There's no call for insults on the user or inflammatory remarks - and we would deal with that through comment flags anyway - but there's no reason to suddenly pause and moderate this *differently* because we may be perceived as "not being nice".

I mean, they decided to post an **exam question** here **in the middle of the exam**.  I don't see any reason to worry about how they feel about us, since it's apparent that they don't *really* care about their *own* academic success.

Comment: I'm sure there will be that one character who is so indifferent to their academic success that they'd even exploit it to use our reaction to their bad-faith question to discredit us elsewhere. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if this has already happened with things that aren't exam questions.

Comment: Which comments do you regard as insults or inflammatory? The only thing that could possibly be construed that way I can see is the "instant F" comment, and even this is only *barely* over the line. It's not an insult for sure, and I'm not sure how you would justify the claim it's inflammatory. It's a statement of extraordinarily common values, which is *chatty*, sure, but inflammatory? The most inflammatory thing there is **the question itself**.

Comment: @jpmc26:  Reacting to an inflammatory question only makes matters worse, so I regard the entirety of the comment section on that question as inflammatory.  There *is* a comment about "getting an instant F" that isn't that useful to anyone within a country mile of this question, too.