# What would have made this interaction nicer for a beginner?

Tags: discussion, welcoming

I recently came across this question *(screenshot below for <10k members)*:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201354/c-how-to-search-data-in-a-linked-list-and-sort-it?noredirect=1

The title and question appear to be asking about searching and sorting a linked list. But the code in the question doesn't involve a list at all. Finally, there's a link to "the real code" on GitHub.

I commented that the code and question didn't match and that we'd need the code posted here on SO in order to keep the question relevant in the future and avoid link rot.

After some back and forth, it became clear the user was not interested in helping us to help him, so I cast the final close vote. I tried to keep my language neutral (feel free to tell me if I failed at that), and tried to supply them with useful solutions for getting an answer, such as clarifying whether they're asking about a linked list or not, since the code doesn't show one. They appeared to me to be giving me the run around in order to avoid doing any more work.

I see that after the last close vote, someone has posted an answer in the comments. The askers responses to that code give me the impression of not wanting to actually understand what was written, but I admit I'm not always the best judge of other people's motivations.

One possible solution would have been to go to GitHub, copy the relevant code and paste it into the question. However, since it's not clear what the question actually is, I'm not sure how to find the minimum amount of code to copy over.

Is there something else I could have done to make this user's first question on SO more welcoming? Or do we consider some users to not be able to be helped because we can't know what they want and they aren't telling us for one reason or another?

Here's the screenshot *(I had to stitch a couple together, apologies for any jagged edges — [T.J.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder))*:

[image]

Comment: Nothing can be done.  Another deadbeat.   Irelevant code in Q, GH link:  Down/close/next, that's it.

Comment: What made it worse is the user trying to answer in comments instead of helping to improve the question.

Comment: Indeed...and the relative low-rep user who answered in the comments should (re)-read the guidelines as well

Comment: Some of these OP's are taking money to get others' homework done, and often have no clue whatsoever about the code they posted or the language in general:(

Comment: Ah  'Hey I forgot to ask. how do I display it after everything is sorted?' - it's a classic help-vampire, stringing out comments to get all its work done:(

Comment: In answer to your question, "What would have made this interaction nicer?" There is a simple solution: **less comments**. The first comment should have been UV by all 47 visitors, and the question should have been closed very quickly via VTC. If & when the user is ready, either the question will be edited and reach Reopen queue, or a new, different question asked.

Comment: Yeah "help-vampire" is accurate. Good point about not feeding the trolls by posting fewer comments. Will do in the future!

Comment: But what about these users that don't feel welcome?..........

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it's all the rhesus-negativity.

Comment: @user1118321 I think this is related to my question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367183/very-very-bad-question-about-an-exam-how-to-be-polite-to-bad-faith-people basically what are we supposed to do when questions suck? The user is going to have a bad experience but it's really cause the user is acting in bad faith (<cough> being terrible)

Comment: So the OP had a list of strings of dates of format 'dd/mm/yyyy', and wanted to sort it by month only. Clearly the OP should have been advised to separate the sort code from the display code (don't embed `viewAll()` calls inside code supposed to be doing the sorting). And yes the OP should have been told to edit the question itself until it was concise and clear, instead of replying in comments. Sometimes we need to go ahead and make the damn edit and show the OP how to be more clear. That often helps. If they're still unclear or unresponsive after that...

Comment: amazing the **effort** some people go to in order to avoid *work*.

Comment: Steam and Stackoverflow have the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nicer'? He made a bad question and tagged it `C++`. By reading meta, I was expecting a snark-fest, but he got an answer to his question and an answer to his follow up question, with little to no snarkiness involved. What else would you want?

Comment: @MartinJames Does Amazon Mechanical Turk apply to coding?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I'm not seeing much in the way of a question here that would be on-topic, even for someone that *had* started here.

The 800-lb gorilla in the room is that the question itself is all over the place and otherwise too broad.  If we distill it to its essential parts, we're left with this...

> I'm currently working on a program that has a linked list. My program need to have a function that can search and sort all the data based on its months but I can't find a good example for me to refer to. ...Please take a look at my code, is this the right way for me to sort it? Please do tell me if you have any better idea to sort it. thanks!

Effectively, the OP is asking us to look at their code and make sure that it's "correct", or to offer improvements on the correctness of their code.

**That's not really what Stack Overflow is here for.**  We're happy to *help*, but we can't proofread their code to make sure that it's correct for their case.  Instead of asking us for help, it reads more like they're asking us to take their place in actually getting their code to work properly.

This has little to do with us being welcoming, and more with us setting expectations on the OP when they ask a question.  In this context, after perusing the comment chain, I'm of the impression that the commentators did everything in their power that they could to get the OP to engage with the proper Q&A format and to actually have us help them with their problem.

This is a lose-lose scenario in my mind; we get the negative rap of not being "welcoming" because we didn't assist this OP in the way they wanted to be assisted, and the OP gets a bad taste in their mouth because they didn't know how to leverage the system in an effective way.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm just trying to check myself and make sure I'm not being unreasonable. This question was pretty irritating.

Comment: Hey...this post is unwelcoming to gorillas..where do I complain?

Comment: Yeah - it's a vamp:(

Comment: @Paulie_D Use "Contact Us" to discuss collaborating with them for a blog on primate inclusiveness.

Comment: @Paulie_D I yearn for a day where Gorillas are judged not for their weight but rather the quality of their posts

Comment: Am I reading it wrong or would the "reduced' question fit quite well into Code Review SE?

Comment: @GabrielLovetro:  [**Yes.  You are reading this wrong.  The reduced question would _not_ fit on Code Review.**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/9874)

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for pointing me to that post! Since I don't use Code Review I figured it was just a place to post code so people would say what's wrong but turns out it's a tad more involved.

Comment: I'm really happy that I got to you in time then @GabrielLovetro. (Tongue in cheek:  "a tad more involved" qualifies as the understatement of the month.)

Answer (score 31):

I think you already did a good job. It's fantastic you want to do even better. The only things that come to mind are:

- It's a delicate balance with "noise," but I try to open with *"Welcome to Stack Overflow!"* (if appropriate) or *"Hi!"* (if not) in an effort to be overtly welcoming up front.
- *"You should read the help section on creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example"* can be read fairly negatively, even if meant neutrally. People don't like being told what they should do. :-) My stock comment (recently revised to try to make it friendlier), shown here with salutation removed since it would have been your second comment, is:

  > The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question above, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

  *(I use a bookmarklet for it. The JavaScript version of that includes a link to how to use Stack Snippets.)*

Basically, I shoot for (even if I sometimes fall short of) being even more welcoming and generous than I may feel, because A) Written communication can be soulless, and B) Any given OP is *not* necessarily one of the 18,752 help-vampires I've dealt with before, and it's not fair to take out my frustration with those 18,752 help-vampires on the OP. Particularly when so many people posting questions are not help-vampires, but people with genuine problems they're willing to work to solve (and work with us to help them solve).

But this is nit-picking at best. Again, FWIW, I think you already did a good job leading the horse to water; the horse refusing to drink it wasn't your fault. Without wanting to be (or seem to be) a jerk, it seems to me the interaction was already at least as positive as the OP deserved it to be. If they walked away thinking "That wasn't much of a positive experience," *good*. They clearly weren't willing to make their question a positive interaction for the people offering to help, or a useful question for others in future. If they are reluctant to repeat the experience, that's a good result for the community. It's unfortunate for the OP, but that's self-generated.

Here's why I think it was at least as positive as it needed to be:

- Unless comments have been removed, no one denigrated or insulted the user
- People (you) **did** put forward positive suggestions for how the question could be improved to the point where people could reasonably help
- No one assumed the OP was male (or at least, didn't address him/her with a male pronoun)

I'm of the camp that is vehemently opposed to any form of bias or negativity on the basis of gender/gender identification, race, national origin, sexual orientation, language ability¹, body shape, or other similar personal properties. But I'm fine with being neutral to borderline negative when people expect help without putting in any effort, without being willing to work within the site's rules and purpose; and who clearly refuse to take on-board useful suggestions for improving their post. *(My only real issue with the recent controversial SE blog post was the conflation of those two things, which to me are completely distinct issues [with different causes, effects, moral dimensions, urgency, and potential solutions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonizing-the-quality-concerned-users-who/366924#comment582425_366924).)*

So I try to open with welcoming-ness, and to continue with friendliness, but if the other side isn't doing their part, eventually I'm happy to be neutral to slightly-negative if necessary — on the basis of the post, not the person.

---

¹ Language ability - I'm opposed to bias or negativity, but naturally we do have to be able to understand the question, and the OP has to be able to understand comments and answers. Sometimes that means suggesting a different site (where one exists in the OP's apparent native language) or suggesting getting help with their English from a friend or coworker. But positively. :-)

Comment: "making the question and its answers useless to people in the future" -  I doubt that a newbie desperately looking for help ([for whatever reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367425/what-would-have-made-this-interaction-nicer-for-a-beginner?cb=1#comment585947_367425)) will be worried about that or even understand that in this moment.

Comment: I like your newby response. Its useful.  Care to share your bookmarklet?

Comment: @jps: Meh, we can only do what we can do. :-)

Comment: @zipzit: It's fairly crude, but it works well enough: `javascript:(function(){var sel = "textarea[name=comment]"; var e = $(document.activeElement).filter(sel); if (!e.length) { e = $(sel + ":visible").first(); } e.val("Message goes here");})();`

Comment: _"'You should read the help section on creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example' can be read fairly negatively [...]"_ ... le sigh... :/

Answer (score 18):

I think the bulk of opportunities to help them have a good experience were missed *as* they were posting the question. It should have been more obvious to them that they shouldn't be posting code *that works* unless they could very specifically describe why the code wasn't optimal, or describe what goal it was failing to meet. Heck, it should have stressed that not posting code is probably a recipe for disaster in *most* cases causing them to think a little more before hitting submit.

I've been (oh, hey Jeff!) constantly talking about overhauling `/ask` to better set people's expectations, and help them give us what's needed in a question without making it feel like a bunch of onerous rules that only picky people care about. That's been *years* in the making and I'm happy to be close to getting something shipped.

The user was made to feel unwelcome because the software failed to prepare them for the inevitable bad reaction their question would receive, and guide them toward asking something different and coming back with more information.

You made them feel like there are real human beings on the other side of those wonky rules, which is great. The other user attempting to help in comments was *super nice*, even though that wasn't actually the kind of thing we'd encourage since it doesn't scale and we can't in any way guarantee the presence of samaritans in a process flow.

So, tl;dr:

- The software is what led them to feel unwelcome, if that's how they felt.
- Human beings probably led them to believe that the problem wasn't *totally* between the chair and the keyboard (that makes me happy!)
- We need to fix the `/ask` page and have needed to do that for years and if Jeff Atwood points that out to me one more time I'm going to [bludgeon him with a giant A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791).

... and we're working on it. But until we do, folks - please remember the software *is* failing people and while we fix it, that little bit of human niceness goes a long way (and will continue to do so, even after we're through making changes).

Comment: But... you need his address to do so, no?

Comment: @Braiam Nope. The A is seriously that big.

Comment: Will you be asking for community input *before* you ship that update?

Comment: We have similar low quality content issues over at Wikipedia, and we are at iteration 2^n of our multi-step wizard aimed at stepping users through the pre-flight of creating an article. Unfortunately, our experience is that almost nobody listens. Certainly SO's on-boarding experience is suboptimal, but until I see the A/B testing showing that a UI update fixes anything, I'll be healthily skeptical.

Comment: The code posted does not work, I promise.  Even someone who didn't know C++ would be able to see the inconsistency between single and doubled equals, both used in the controlling expressions of `if`.  As a C++ user I can further say that the `substr()` near the top of the function is useless because the first `str2 = "01"` overwrites it, and there was no intervening use of the value.  As a result none of the `if` statements act on the user's own data.  We surely wouldn't want to be burying that user with advice on what to do to get feedback on working code.

Comment: Please tell me that, _"working on it"_ is going to amount to more than just a few text templates in a giant `<textarea>`. Wizardify all the things. #pitofsuccess

Comment: *"we can't in any way guarantee the presence of samaritans in a process flow"* :-) The SE network relies entirely on the presence of (good) samaritans in the process flow; else, no questions would be answered other than by paid SE staff. Said samaritans are not always *nice*, though. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Overall this doesn't look like too horrible an experience. Ignoring what the poster could have done better, then...

The *community* could do better by not attempting to answer the question in comments, or overall not attempt to answer questions that can't be answered. The whole comment history is sending out the wrong signals about how Stack Overflow works. As a result of this, the question got deleted and the OP did not learn how to ask questions for the next time. Everyone loses.

A link to how to post an MCVE could have been provided with the first comment, so that the OP didn't need to drag in the full code. But that's just a nit-pick, since the automated close message gives a link to how-to-ask, which in turn gives a link to MCVE. If someone wants to post a manual comment, that's all well and good.

Regarding tags:

The question was actually properly tagged from the start. Otherwise using the wrong tags tend to cause unnecessary hostility. Those who find a poorly tagged question early: make sure to edit the tags ASAP, even if the question needs to be closed. Fixing the tags early on might reduce the number of downvotes significantly.

In this particular case, look for two hot potatoes: no double-tagging C and C++ (C would obviously be wrong here) and absolutely make sure that the [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linked-list) tag is there. Lots of developers tend to throw up each time they see yet another broken linked list implementation by yet another confused student, which is why many users have this particular tag on ignore list.

Similar hot potatoes exist all over Stack Overflow for various domain-specific tags (don't tag your JavaScript question with Java and so on).

Comment: *"The whole comment history is sending out the wrong signals about how SO works."* Well, I wouldn't say the *whole* history. Specifically, not user1118321's part. :-)

Comment: This answer is great, but this part is *particularly* great: *"The community could do better by not attempting to answer the question in comments, or overall not attempt to answer questions that can't be answered."* We have the FGITW problem, and it's a hard problem, and we haven't solved it yet. If we could all, collectively, hang back when the question isn't ready to be answered, that would markedly improve things.

Comment: Great answer. But I would go even further than `not attempting to answer the question in comments`. Just don't comment *at all* when there are other valid comments. Upvote the first good comment, VTC and move on.

Answer (score 6):

I think you've done a good job. I find it very difficult to answer questions like this. The user doesn't know what a linked list is, they are clueless about sorting algorithms, and they are trying to teach themselves programming by searching for example code that does exactly what they want. They don't need an answer to this question, they need a basic introductory course in programming, and that's something we clearly can't provide in an SO answer.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who cast a close vote on this question, my primary motivation for doing so was that the plain english was completely un-parseable. If a person can't explain in plain text what it is that they need, we should not leave the question around for others to waste time guessing.

This was confounded further by the code being non-sensical (why code not one, but two `for` loops, neither of which uses the index variable to access an array?)

Also, the link to the code is a red flag for me. If you need to link to code, you have not provided a MCVE, and therefore you are generally off-topic.

Occasionally, when casting close votes, I will leave a comment advising what can be done to improve the question. I would say I do this in roughly 10-15% of the cases. This question didn't even meet that standard, meaning I viewed it as showing so little effort that it was unworthy of someone answering.