# We-are-not-a-code-writing-service comments. Are they the good, the bad, or the ugly?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, helpful-flags, code-of-conduct

There's a  lot of "We are not a code writing service" comments being flagged. The flag rate for them is increasing and there's now some custom flags complaining about users who write this in their comments frequently.

1. What are the expectation of the community of how these flags are handled?
2. Are these types of comments within keeping of the new [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)?
3. How can we write them to be helpful?

Comment: I mean... they're by definition unwelcoming. Just like some other forms of criticism, even if they're not wrong. Just a side effect of putting the rules into a readable list imo.

Comment: At the same time... they aren't wrong; and "give me teh codez" is all too common. How are we supposed to communicate that it isn't acceptable? Also this is why I didn't want "unwelcoming language" in the CoC (and they did replace it with "unfriendly".)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Communicating that something isn't acceptable isn't welcoming.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: By closing them I guess?

Comment: @BDL i mean... yeah, if only that would happen often enough.

Comment: I'm with @BradleyDotNET on this. Requirement dumps and homework dumps are not welcome here, so being welcoming to them is giving mixed signals.

Comment: @KevinB: But if the question doesn't get closed (which is terrible), then the comment will also not make an impact. But I'm neutral on this, can't really say if this comments should stay or not.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are very welcome to be here, we love having your here. It's just your question that we are having troubles welcoming, because we are not a code writing service. So you are welcome and we welcome you, please feel that you are welcomed, but your question is going to get closed and deleted.

Comment: @DavyM that made me smile.

Comment: If we're sticking strictly to the CoC, they shouldn't. Just as a lot of other things that are commonly left as comments shouldn't be (but will likely continue to be)

Comment: @YvetteColomb sounds like SOCVR V2.0

Comment: @KevinB 'if only that would happen often enough' well, the close-vote system could be made more effective if the first close-vote on a question prevented answers being posted for some period, 30 minutes, say.  That would give enough time for the other 4 close-votes to be be applied to bad questions before the FGITW rep-whatevers cough up a dupe or other low-quality answer.

Comment: yeah... but that'd be so easy to use for trolling someone, or preventing further answers. would have to be carefully implemented

Comment: @YvetteColomb umm.. I think some comments got deleted, so just ignore me ;)

Comment: @MartinJames ah I gotcha, it was turned into an answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372171/3956566

Comment: In all the years that I've been on SO, I have **never** seen a homework dump or requirement dump improved. No matter how nice we asked. So instead of dealing with the comment, solve the problem at its source: delete the homework dump or requirement dump.

Comment: @S.L.Barth "being welcoming to them is giving mixed signals" - reductio ad absurdum - let's just swear at and degrade people asking bad questions because we don't want them here.

Comment: @Dukeling Well, that would be the other extreme... but "we are not a code writing service" is not swearing. I myself don't think of it as degrading.(I think with _reduction ad absurdum_ you refer to your own statement here, that you're playing devil's advocate... but I'm not sure. If you think my logic is fallacious, let me know.)

Comment: @S.L.Barth Swearing and degrading is the absurd logical conclusion of being unwelcoming. Closing and deleting (and arguably downvoting) is unwelcoming, but "necessary" to get rid of the post. Leaving an unwelcoming comment doesn't really *do* anything (good) - chances are you're just hurting feelings, starting an argument or fast-tracking the asker to ignoring any feedback that's not an answer. (If you want to say the comment is *not* unwelcoming, we'd just be back to an argument I've had way too many times already)

Comment: But... we are a code-writing service: [How to achieve the following automatic numbering using css OR js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51734084). OP just specifies some requirements and out comes code! Some by a relatively high-rep user even...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Maybe that's the trick: we should advertise that Stack Overflow is an awful code writing service, which only works every Nth question or so. ;)

Comment: @HereticMonkey there is a phenomenon for that, it is called as "rep whoring" (excuse me for the phrase).

Comment: Personally I've always posted *Voting to close as off-topic for the following reason SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts* if this is now deemed to fall foul of the CoC then there should be an auto-tag/link to a page that defines why a gimme teh codez is unsuitable and what is needed. I'm not going to start typing out an elaborate and detailed explanation that fully explains why and what SO really is about for every such question I see. I spend more time now cleaning up and close-voting than I do answering

Comment: @EdChum You could link to http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ .

Comment: @S.L.Barth true but that is an off-site link, not a SO approved page, also it's about why I downvoted which I didn't necessarily do although it does detail the reasons why the question in current form is inappropriate, the other issue is whether that site itself doesn't fall foul of the CoC, I think the offensive part of the CoC will be difficult to manage. You can't control whether the OP or other users will find your comment offensive, despite how you phrase it IMO. Still it's worth suggesting adopting something similar to that link or a close reason

Comment: @S.L.Barth comments linking to that site are also being flagged! I took that site out of all my autocomments. Such a shame, so much effort has gone into it and it gives people the opportunity to ping the user for a vote reversal. How proactive can you be. It shows the people who are not truly interested in learning how the site works and view any comment that doesn't include an answer a nuisance.

Comment: @Servy That's not true. You can be welcoming to someone while also telling them something is not acceptable. Remember that you should strive to separate people from their behavior when addressing one or the other. While Davy M's comment is obviously quite on the nose, it does hint at how one could phrase such a comment.

Comment: @TylerH The comment was ironic.

Comment: @Servy probably best to follow the CoC's advice then, and 'avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes'.

Comment: @EdChum [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) [Stack Overflow checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) (and, by extension, [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/))

Comment: @dukeling but that's a meta and I'd have to search for it, it'd be useful if this was something on the help / tour page so it's easy to find and link to I agree with those links but it'd be useful if these were readily accessible

Comment: @EdChum I agree, but we can only work with what we've got.

Comment: @dukeling true but if the rules have changed, personally I feel we don't want to alienate old and new users by making life more difficult, personally I find this all a bit much but then I'm not a new user and of a different generation and culture

Comment: @S.L.Barth I see it occasionally. A homework dump that gets "show your efforts", and a few minutes later, the OP comes back and "Oh, I forgot about that" plus some code. Sometimes a real attempt, sometimes it more looks like an empty template, probably part of the assignment itself.

Comment: @YvetteColomb idownvoted links are flagged ... for what reason? And flagging is one thing, but what then? The comment gets removed, or the commenter will run into a "warning"?

Comment: @GhostCat they have been flagged as R/A .

Comment: @YvetteColomb People are flagging idownvotedbecau.se links as R/A? Seriously? That site is the _one_ resource that actually makes new users improve their questions. It doesn't talk down to them, it explains clearly and gently what is wrong and why. Please tell me you decline these flags.

Comment: I think the `idownvotedbecau.se` part is a bit passive-aggressive -- people do get upset and take downvotes personally. I would use those links in comments if the site was named something different as the pages themselves are very useful (plus I don't downvote).

Comment: @ialarmedalien I feel like that site can be very patronizing too

Comment: I always flag comments that are **only** links to idownvotedbecau.se as "no longer needed". I think comments like that are unfriendly, and in my opinion, if you are too lazy to explain your reasons in the comment itself, then don't bother to comment at all. That is technically the same as deleting link-only answers. Personally, I would have no problem with that site getting the same treatment as lmgtfy

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - "If you are too lazy to explain your reasons in the comment itself" - what about when you are writing the *exact same* reasons for the 100th time? That's the service that idownvotedbecau.se provides. If SO allowed us to save canned comments and re-use them, that site would be far less necessary.

Comment: @rmunn I simply don't think that a comment that is only a linked to idownvotedbecau.se will be well-received by the recipient of that comment. At best they will ignore it, at worst they'll get agitated by the passive-aggressiveness of that. In other words using that link is not worth the time, and the only reason you are using it is to feel good about yourself (as in: there, I have left 'feedback'), while not spending time to actually educate the user. Things like that don't contribute positively (and maybe negatively), so you could just as well not post comments that are only a link.

Comment: @ialarmedalien What would you call that site? Finding a better name isn't easy. Maybe "HowToImproveYourQuestion.com"... but that still sounds  passive-aggressive.

Comment: @S.L.Barth That's much less passive-aggressive than 'idownvoted...', though. It's very tricky as you're essentially telling someone that they have done something badly/wrong, and that'll put some people on the defensive regardless of how nicely you say it! icantansweryourquestionbecau.se?

Comment: "give me teh codez" are unwelcomed and deserves to be unwelcomed. We are not obligated to welcome everything are we?

Comment: @tweray: The consensus (if votes still mean that) seems to be that [we don't want to welcome everything, no](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366839/103167).

Comment: @S.L.Barth yes, they are. Insane. The effort that went into that site and it gives people the opportunity to have downvotes reversed. I decline, but I'm not sure there's a consensus on that.  It's something the mods will need to actually discuss. I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thank you! I think I've seen some mods feeling those comments should be removed. There is simply one compelling argument why I comment with these links... because **it works**! It's gotten new users to improve their post. So that site is on to something.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I personally like them. But that's an opinion, not a rule as such. I took them out of my auto comments as some people think they're rude. In fact I'm commenting less on main. Just voting, closing or deleting (posts I mean)

Comment: I feel like those comments are just a sign that our close reasons are not covering enough. I’m often in the situation where I want to close a question because it’s clearly off topic but there isn’t a *real* good fitting close reason for that. – I then just pick a somewhat random one, but I could see that many others simply don’t close vote at all. And that makes these comments more fitting: “I cannot close vote, so I at least tell you that you shouldn’t ask this”. – If we had better close reasons, we wouldn’t need to post all these “unwelcoming” comments.

Answer (score 55):

So... There are *definitely* people who treat the site like a code-writing service.

- There are students - freshly-minted every year - who never got the message that the expensive education they're selling their souls for isn't gonna pay for itself if they don't learn anything. They're desperate to pass a test or complete some assignment, driven by that white-hot blinding *fear* that only comes with realizing far too late that you've made a terrible mistake.
- There are working programmers whose sole on-the-job training is "this is Stack Overflow, your deadline is Friday". Their livelihood, their literal *daily bread*, depends on getting someone to do for them what they cannot.

Near as I can tell, both groups are *relatively* small, dwarfed by the ranks of well-intentioned but inexperienced students and workers... Though this minority often makes up for what they lack in numbers with raw cussedness. Almost everyone else has *options* - they don't *have* to ask questions here, they can ask friends, classmates, co-workers, they can do their own research, maybe even read their textbooks.

So any time you see one of these questions, you gotta ask yourself: is this someone who just needs a bit of friendly guidance, or is this [a dangerously desperate individual](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367183/very-very-bad-question-about-an-exam-how-to-be-polite-to-bad-faith-people/367188#367188)?

At least, you *should* be asking yourself that if you want to do *anything productive with your time*. Because... I don't think I've ever seen anyone say, in response to such a comment,

> Oh! Dear me, I honestly thought Stack Overflow *was* a code-writing service. Such an embarassing mistake, please accept my undying gratitude for the clarification - I'll leave straight away and find an *actual* code-writing service!

I don't read every comment; maybe this has happened. But... It kinda seems like these comments are more "virtue signalling" for the commenters than they are anything useful to the askers *or anyone else*. [As Pops wrote years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134986/how-can-the-what-stack-overflow-is-not-post-be-improved/134994#134994) about the old "What Stack Overflow is Not" comments,

> In other words, linking to WSOiN is the "I just walked five extra steps to throw away a candy wrapper instead of littering, so I've done my part to protect the environment for this year" of the SO world. It really is the least you can do.
>
> This is just a human nature thing; people who normally put in a certain level of effort may do much less when you give them an easier alternative that still lets them feel like they've somehow contributed. I don't even mind WSOiN too much when it's used in conjunction with other efforts, rather than instead of them.

The last time I deleted one of these "code-writing service" comments, it was on a question that... was an obvious duplicate. Took me *maybe* a minute to find a whole pile of older questions, pick the best one, close the question, and drop a related link into the thread. I was the 4th close voter and the 6th commenter - so while a whole pile of folks were competing for the best way to tell the author that SO couldn't do what they wanted, nobody bothered to tell them that SO already *had* done what they wanted, ages ago, and if they'd known the right search terms they could've found it themselves.

Even if you don't believe these comments are *inherently* rude, the sheer inefficiency and dishonesty that rides their coattails has gotta be a bit off-putting. If you're worried about dishonest students, maybe start by not pulling the same lazy, manipulative crap that they are; if you want to help *receptive* askers, then focus on giving them something they can actually **use**.

I've deleted these comments pretty readily for years and don't intend to stop now.

Comment: "Took me maybe a minute to find a whole pile of older questions, pick the best one, close the question, and drop a related link into the thread."
Unfortunately, this might convince the OP the next time to just dump his assignment as well, because "within the first ten responses, there'll be a link to what I can just copy paste". It's not that SO CAN'T do what he wanted, it's that SO (rightfully so) expects him/her to (at the very least) try for himself, but a lot of times, it's just a "do my work for me" request. Sure, the response might be rude, but, then again, ...

Comment: wasn't the request rude as well? We are, after all, volunteers. Why should we do the work (s)he wants to be rewarded (wages, degree, ... ) for? I agree closing questions like this is a good approach, but if nobody posts a "why" in a way the OP understands (rude or not), chances are they have no idea why it's closed, and will post it again. If the OP has a history of making well-formed and informative questions, and this is the first "gimme", or if it's the first post of the user, a more friendly approach would be nice, but it's not always the commenters that should get a slap on the wrist

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not misunderstanding this answer: Is your proposal that we handle "write-my-code" questions by finding a duplicate and post a link to the duplicate (if it exists)?

Comment: I decided to unaccept this and allow the community to float which answers they want to be at the top. In accord with being a representative of the community, as opposed to an advocate of the SE company.

Comment: I've removed this particular comment from the SOCVR library (is one of the oldest canned comments). Most people autopull it with Autocomments so hopefully you'll see less of these in the future.

Comment: @Stultuske I have something of a problem with people calling such questions rude. Inconsiderate, perhaps, but I don't think I would call them rude... certainly not if it is the OP's first question. The discussion about rude behavior or language lately re: the CoC is in a different league from the kind of 'rudeness' that a homework dump question would count as. Remember that we are still supposed to assume good faith, and that means it's highly unlikely that someone is going around posting questions with honeypot titles thinking "I'm going to waste as much of peoples' time as possible w/ this!"

Comment: @Stultuske Rather, they are almost always genuinely wanting help and usually they think Stack Overflow is the place to get it. Part of this is always going to be unavoidable as SO grows in global popularity, people will share info about it and their own perceptions of it... one person may say "Oh, SO is a great place to get help from programmers if you have some question about <insert complex, interesting question here>", while another may tell people "yes, I recommend SO for learning how to code! It's where I learned!". Those two sentences can convey very different things to people.

Comment: @Stultuske obviously there are some trolls out there that post a bunch of spammy/rude questions and get banned and deleted shortly thereafter. Or if someone is repeatedly told their questions are low-quality, off-topic, get closed, etc., but continues, then yes, then their behavior is probably considered unequivocally rude (after all, they have not been listening to our advice/words/the system telling them that their questions need work or are off-topic, etc)... but until then, I would not be OK with calling those questions rude. You can always skip/avoid a question if you want, after all.

Comment: 'we are still supposed to assume good faith' I have no problem with that - I always do.  If I open a question in good faith and then find out it's a homework/requirement dump, then no further assumption is required and all good faith is out the window.

Comment: I never really bought that argument, @Stultuske; most folks don't ask two questions... Most folks don't ask *one* - they search. If you close a question as a duplicate, that's another path for folks searching next time. If you scold the asker... It's just a dead-end in search.

Comment: @TylerH when I see posts (first time posters, so, admittedly, maybe not the most experienced) that basically say "here is a vague description of what I need. I need it urgently" (and I see quite a lot of those)
1. they did agree with the rules upon becoming a member
2. they are very well aware that we help during our spare time, or off moments at work, meaning our time is quite valuable as well
3. they know very well we are not getting paid for it, and they don't have to pay for it.
In that light, yes, it is a bit rude.

Comment: @Shog9 unfortunately, a whole lot of people don't search. In a lot of cases, they add a vague description of what they (think) they want, and expect us to magically solve it. No code, no error message, nothing to go on.
I'm not talking about scolding, I do, however, usually inform the OP that we are not required to do his work, that he should at least try himself first.

Comment: @Stultuske IME, it's a lot rude.  Much more rude than most so-called 'snarky' comments and, on Sundays, much more prevalent:(   Most of the questions on the C tag are drone/slave orders for complete assignment answers.

Comment: @MartinJames that's not what good faith means; you clicking on a question link has nothing to do with good faith in the asker. What good faith means is assuming the OP is asking a genuine question and if they've done something wrong, either they truly aren't aware, or that they tried to do it right and this was the best they could do given their inexperience. Saying otherwise re: good faith is disingenuous at best and definitely *not* good faith on your part. Also a reminder, **homework questions are not off-topic on Stack Overflow**.

Comment: A "whole lot" of people do almost anything on Stack Overflow, because there are a whole lot of arbitrary groups >= "a whole lot" in size contained within SO's massive and yet constantly-changing base of users, @Stultuske. However, the vast, vast *majority* of people using SO **do** search; it's literally the primary interface to the site for all but a relative sliver of users. Folks tend to convert to askers only when search is unproductive.

Comment: @Shog9 remember: I'm talking about the group that doesn't search before dropping an assignment on SO

Comment: And remember, this is a minority of users *period*, and a minority of askers, @Stultuske. You're essentially identifying as your target *people who don't use Google* - and not because they're super into DuckDuckGo. Assuming you can even differentiate them accurately from the wave of poorly-educated students arriving fresh each year without the vocabulary they need to search *effectively*, what's your goal? You gonna sit around and walk them through the process of learning to search? You gonna best Google's billions of $ of work putting search into *everything* and somehow convince them?

Comment: You don't seem to work the stacks much anymore.  It *used* to be a minority and easy to deal with.  But not anymore, not since you opened the flood gates with the changes in 2012 and 2013.  You are going to do this again, basic reason why you get so much pushback from users about it.  SO users are deeply concerned about this, SO got to be a primary programming resource and it has been steadily heading for a steep cliff.  Professional programmers have a hard time getting help today.  Seems the company is on that path as well, you gotta be a bit concerned about your livelihood.

Comment: If I was gonna fixate on my livelihood, I wouldn't have taken this job @Hans; last I checked, programming still pays a lot better than "CMing". Which, of course, is why so many people are getting into it, unprepared. And these information-free comments do nothing for that; if anything, they just contribute to driving away the remaining people who might actually post something interesting. [But I've been saying that for years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83019/are-stack-overflow-people-still-nice/83021#83021).

Comment: @Shog9 let's say you get a post, and you copy paste their question (without changes) in google and click search, the first x results give exactly what they're looking for, that is one way to know they didn't bother. It may be only a minority of members, but, as you say, only a low percentage of members post questions, meaning that minority might just be a majority of askers. (it might also depend on the tags you usually check).
Some days, there are hardly any questions like that, the other day, the forum is flooded with them

Comment: "People search"? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760363/has-anybody-ever-practically-coded-the-external-sort-to-sort-and-merge-two-large#comment90479923_51760363)'s a recent example. It's a pure "gimme codez" question. I directed OP to Wikipedia (if I were snarkier, it would be a perfect candidate for a lmgfty link) that actually even links to the Java code, the very thing OP's looking for - and OP didn't even bother to look at it. It took a real strength of will to not comment and not be not nice. The Q is closed now, do you think OP knows why? I don't want to be welcoming...

Comment: Yes, people search @Amadan... Even that person searched: according to the logs, they searched for that question on Stack Overflow and reviewed two of the resulting questions prior to asking their own question. Of course... As you found when you gave them a third result, just because you can search doesn't mean you can or will make use of the results. But, still a good reason NOT to litter the site with superfluous comments. You did the right thing: your comment is informative; if not for the asker, then at least for anyone else who had to read that question. That's *something*.

Comment: I don’t want to make a comment, I want to close the question, and I want the close reason to be useful.  It’s not a duplicate, it’s not  unclear what they are asking, it’s not too broad, it’s not primary opinion. That leaves off topic because, and it’s not about general h/s, not infrastructure or admin, not recommending a tool, seeking debugging help (I wish), why isn’t this code working (again I wish, much more invested), it is no one has yet written the code for him, doesn’t belong to another stack.  Which leaves other and leaving a comment saying....”SO is not a code writing service”....

Comment: ...I would like SO to come up with a nice wording for that and make it a close reason.  This is not a rare case where making a dedicated close reason wouldn’t make sense, this is an everyday occurrence.  I don’t want to be mean, I want SO To be clear.

Comment: "Took me maybe a minute to find a whole pile of older questions, pick the best one, close the question" - okay, and how long did it take to close the other n-1 older questions to the best one, after reviewing them to make sure they were appropriate as such; or else to VTC them for other appropriate reasons? IMX, that's the part that doesn't normally get done; and that's the main reason why the site drowns in a sea of bad questions *that makes the actually good dupes harder to find*.

Comment: @jmoreno IMX, such questions usually *really are* too broad, or as we say it nowadays, they need more focus. Generally the *reason* you get that "ugh, OP wants to use us as a code-writing service" feeling is because there are *steps* to solving the underlying problem, and each of those steps potentially represents a separate question (although it could be a duplicate, or something that OP knows how to do). But if we want Stack Overflow to be "a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming", then that includes easy ones.

Answer (score 32):

1. We shouldn't be writing them, [for reasons of visibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371440/1079354).  If they're introducing noise, they are ripe for removal.
2. Meh.  This is that gray area that no one really clarified.  We're really *not* here to write code for everyone, yet a lot of people take umbrage with this fact.  We*, the faithful few that commentate in the hopes of informing at least one soul that this is not what the site is for now find ourselves in a Catch-22, and are at the mercy of whichever moderator happens across our flagged comment.
3. You ***can't***, and there's no point to expend energy on trying.  It's too hidden to be of much lasting value, and given their temporal nature, there's a non-zero chance of it not lasting long enough for it to have had its lasting impact.

<sup>*: Royal "we"; those who still commentate on questions with this message.</sup>

Comment: as usual a sensible answer.

Comment: "We shouldn't be writing them, for reasons of visibility" Why would we need visibility if the question is a code-writing request. There's nothing there to see or preserve, the question should just be deleted, along with all comments.

Comment: @Lundin:  That's kind of what I'm getting at.  When the question is deleted, do we have a guarantee that the OP even saw the message?  How visible of a warning is it to others who might want to try to ask that same kind of question?

Answer (score 27):

I see the comment as more of a call to action for other users to use their close votes. Maybe a better alternative would be to make existing close votes more visible to users who have the privilege to cast close votes. Then... you can just cast your vote, knowing others will see it without your comment.

At that point maybe find a way of informing users who leave comments like this of the new feature.

Comment: Do we really need a "call to action"? You can see that the question has close votes on it. What more do you need? Furthermore, we want people to close because *they* think it is merited, not because they are going along with what others say. We shouldn't want to peer-pressure people into VTCing.

Comment: Yes, considering how few questions that should be closed actually end up closed.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  People get **upset** when they see their question has close votes or downvotes on it like you wouldn't believe, man.  It's  like, a personal trigger for some people.

Comment: That said, I do agree with your sentiment.  Pile-on voting is very much a thing and is very much not what we want to be practicing.

Comment: @Makoto: That cannot be helped. We shouldn't stop performing vital moderation tasks because some people take them personally.

Comment: The SOCVR chatroom already has a script that allows notification of existing close votes on a question and allows an extended explanation of why they are appropriate.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Trust me, I get that.  But I'm not the one that needs convincing of this fact.  Nor is Kevin, for that matter.

Comment: @Makoto yeh, but you kinda get acclimatised to the downvotes once they reach -100.

Comment: @MartinJames Now if only all of that discussion and functionality were exposed to every 3k+ user to encourage them to use their CVs :-)

Comment: _"Maybe a better alternative would be to make existing close votes more visible to users who have the privilege to cast close votes."_ you are aware of the existence of the close votes review queue, right?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that place where singular votes on bad questions never get seen?

Comment: @KevinB That only happens because not enough people are using it.

Comment: My point exactly!!!

Comment: @Makoto Posters may get upset when they see downvotes but, I get just as upset whenever I see objectively bad questions get upvotes.  Sympathy upvotes are just as bad as pile-on downvotes.

Answer (score 26):

**A *question* which is a code-writing request with no effort shown is very rude.**

It is disrespectful to those who spend their free time answering questions free of charge, and it is also against numerous on-topic rules for the site.

> 1. What are the expectation of the community of how these flags are handled?

If someone flags such a comment as rude, but not the far ruder question, they are flagging the wrong content. I would expect the moderator to first of all look at the question that resulted in such a comment. If it is indeed a code-writing request with no effort shown, the whole question, including all answers and comments, should be deleted from the site. Disciplinary action should be taken against the poster of the question.

This must surely be in line with SO's new policy. We don't accept rudeness.

If the question was fine but there was still such a comment, the comment is not needed and should simply be deleted, with no disciplinary action.

> 2. Are these types of comments within keeping of the new Code of Conduct?

I really don't see how they could be. Either the question they commented on is a rude code-writing request, in which case the comment was justified. Or it isn't, in which case the comment is simply superfluous.

> 3. How can we write them to be helpful?

They are probably not very helpful, as the kind of rude posters who are the origin of such comments are not likely to change their ways. However, the comments are most often not rude either.

Comment: `I would expect the moderator to first of all look at the question that resulted in such a comment.` No. You are doubling an already large mod workload. `Disciplinary action should be taken against the poster of the question.` Again, no. There are already processes in place for those who repeatedly ask poor questions.

Comment: @jpp thanks for mentioning the workload and the disciplinary action. The post bans are automated, so there's not a lot mods need to do about people posting poor questions. If a comment is in any way curious, or the flagger is, I will read the whole comment thread. To gain perspective and check for other rude comments, or vindictive comment flagging. For many comments, checking the post or the thread is not necessary.

Comment: There's merit in this answer. For any active member scrolling to answer questions, it does get tough seeing the stream of questions where there's no effort on part of the OP. Sometimes it's ignorance, sometimes it's arrogance.. whatever. It does get tiring. Which is why it's important the site gives it's members the tools to discard of this type of question expediently.

Comment: @Lundin I agree that moderators should always visit the Q&A page to see full context before acting on a flagged comment, but, unfortunately, that is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: @TylerH the [answer I recently got from moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372117/839601) suggests that they typically check questions that receive comment flags. Bad news are, they seem to be somewhat reluctant to delete. OTOH good news are they don't hesitate to close: "We immediately close the bad questions when we see it. Even if a post does not have any rude comments, and we see that it's bad, we close it..."

Comment: +50. This seemed to be the only answer that actually comes from a community member. All the hate towards the commenters when the focus should have always been on the askers

Comment: Leaving aside my substantive disagreements with this answer, your response to point 2 seems hard-to-interpret and possibly self-contradictory to me. You say that you don't see how these comments could be in keeping with the code of conduct - i.e. that you think they are a violation of the code of conduct - but then in the next sentence say that they are often justified. I'm a bit confused by what you're actually trying to say - whether the first sentence is a typo, or whether you're saying that these comments violate the code of conduct but that you approve of them anyway.

Answer (score 21):

There needs to be guidance as to what constitutes acceptable and "welcoming" as a response to poor questions. For requirement-dump questions specifically, in my opinion, *SO is not a code-writing service* is unhelpful.

Frequently, a new SO asker will:

- not understand what such a comment means
- glance confusedly at a stream of upvoted comments criticising their question
- vent at the -10 and dropping score
- see their "important" question put down by a "Closed... Too broad" banner
- halfheartedly skim a page of instructions on what they are meant to be doing
- give up as they don't know enough to pinpoint the nature of their problem

It's not *all* a result of the comment, but the aggregate impression is akin to a personal attack. The response is more emotional than rational. Educating beforehand that the comment or score isn't a reflection on the questioner but the question doesn't work.

More helpful:

> Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Simple, concise, direct. *Show us your code* can only yield a Boolean response. In my experience, it *often* reaps dividends. Moreover, I have **never** been accused of being harsh, critical or unhelpful on the basis of such a comment, even when I add a downvote + vote-to-close.

Often, I come back and see a good edit, or my comment upvoted 3 times and the question closed or deleted. All good outcomes.

Comment: The 'Welcome to SO. Please' is irrelevant.  gcc/clang doesn't have 'Hello, I'm your friendly neighbourhood compiler, here are your 227 error-messages, thank you for choosing me to handle your code'.  Just stick to what is required, and then nobody can moan with any creedence.

Comment: It's not irrelevant. Because it works. I used to list demands: "Provide this, give me that. Do this, do that." Caused friction. Adding the Welcome & Please actually  help here with minimal kowtowing. Take those words out and read it aloud. If a colleague spoke to me like that, I wouldn't be keen to respond.

Comment: For all of the insight and empathy you have for a new SO user, please apply the same thoughtfulness to the MCVE page.  For new, inexperienced coders who already do not perceive how their question is interpreted by others, they will certainly struggle to understand what an MCVE is even after reading the page.  It takes significant practice and debugging skills to be able to produce well-worded MCVEs. Why won't they halfheartedly skim the MCVE page just as any other "page of instructions"?

Comment: @CPerkins, Maybe my experience is different to yours (I look at well-established tags [python] and [pandas]). Usually, OP gets the message, but if they do ask for further advice I always give more specific guidance ("start by printing this bit, try splitting your program in chunks, etc"). There's a bit of self-interest in my advice (less time to write), but it seems to work fairly often.

Comment: -1 because not all questions require an MCVE, and I suspect that a request for an MCVE would be unreasonable on most questions that get criticised as "code-writing" requests. Debugging questions are rarely interesting, and blindly demanding that new users turn their questions into debugging questions is unlikely to produce *good* questions even if it manages to produce acceptable ones.

Comment: @MarkAmery, I think you're reading a bit too much into my answer. The question explicitly states this is about alternatives to `We-are-not-a-code-writing-service comments`. Nowhere do I say this is appropriate for every situation.

Comment: @jpp I'd actually go further and say that the comment you propose here is also bad in all circumstances. An MCVE is meant to accompany a question about *why the MCVE produces the behaviour it does* - that's what it means to say that it's an "example" of something. Code that instead accompanies a how-to question and shows "where you got stuck" is almost by definition not an MCVE; it's just an incomplete attempt (and probably not a helpful addition to the question). Asking for an MCVE that is also an "attempt" at solving a problem is close to being a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 20):

Either "bad" or "ugly" depending upon what sort of question they're being applied to.

The reason I think these comments are *never* good is that they're too vague. Clearly, we do in fact write code for people; many (perhaps most) answers contain code. It's therefore non-obvious what "code-writing service" is even supposed to mean, or why we don't qualify as one. Indeed, Tiny Giant recently controversially argued that [actually, we *are* a code-writing service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368541/1709587); right now, that post has 37 upvotes.

So *at best* these comments get used to criticise genuinely bad, criticism-worthy questions in a vague way that doesn't directly address what's actually wrong with the question, instead hoping to imply what the specific problem is via an unclear statement about the nature of Stack Overflow that many of its veteran users don't even think is *true*. That specific problem might be:

- that an answer would simply require *too much* code, making the question "too broad", and that the asker needs to ask a question about a narrower piece of their system. Or...
- that the asker has left too many details of the desired behavior unspecified, leaving them as judgement calls in the hands of the answerer, making the question "unclear" and in need of a more precise problem specification. Or...
- that the question consists of an arbitrary collection of specific business or homework requirements such that, while it is answerable with a short amount of code, it doesn't cleanly illustrate how to do any *particular* task, nor answer any *particular* question, that somebody might later want to Google for. This sort of question - sometimes referred to as a "requirements dump" - used to be a good candidate for a "too localized" closure; now that we don't have that reason, if you squint you can sort-of rationalize closing them as "too broad" (on the basis that the question should've been narrowed down to a smaller part of the task) or "unclear" (on the basis that we can't tell which part of the problem the asker is stuck on), which people do in fact do (me included).

Perhaps there are other bad question paradigms that people are trying to gesture at when they about us not being a "code-writing service", but those are the three I can think of.

(And if you've previously left these comments, thinking your meaning was obvious, and yet some of the possible meanings I've listed above had *never occurred to you*, that's just the perfectly ordinary [illusion of transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion_of_transparency) at work.)

In all of those cases, explaining the specific problem like I've done above is far more useful than vaguely stating that we're not a "code-writing service", whatever that means.

The *ugly* cases of these comments are where people leave them on:

- narrowly-specified, broadly-applicable how-to questions about how to do some common task in a particular language. Such questions are among the most helpful questions on the site and don't deserve criticism, but sometimes attract it anyway (perhaps inevitably, since one reader's timeless how-to question on a common task is another reader's requirements dump).
- debugging questions. Sure, I guess you might write a few lines of code in the process of explaining why someone else's code doesn't work, but framing "Why doesn't this code work?" as a request for "code-writing" is unnatural and confusing.
- questions that are unambiguously not asking for any code to be written at all, rendering the comment a complete non-sequitur. Yes, this happens.

I have not once seen an instance where I thought one of these comments was helpful. They just vaguely convey "I do not like your question" without articulating why. An unexplained downvote does that job just as well, and less noisily.

Comment: I coudn't agree more.

Comment: I was considering adding an answer here until I read yours. This is perfect.

Comment: These comments "just vaguely convey 'I do not like your question' without articulating why." Spot on.

Comment: I agree, this response hits the nail on the head.

Comment: also see Brad Larson [comment in that answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368538/what-have-i-done-wrong-considering-rudeness-politeness/368541#comment594227_368541).

Answer (score 13):

It's pretty hard to see how these would be "good". I remember the days when it was fashionable to link to specific answers in the ["What Stack Overflow is Not"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not) question on MSE. [That was stopped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137795/242059) and rightfully so (and I say this as someone who not only posted such comments, but who also still has that question favorited).

If you can't do better than saying what SO is not, then it's probably best to just downvote and move on.

For the specific points:

1. Unless the comment says something more than this, delete it.
2. No. Nor did they follow "Be Nice". That's why we shifted to not posting "What SO is not" comments, and I see no reason why these would be treated any differently.
3. This is harder. The ideal thing would be to have some page on the site that talks about this problem in particular, so that someone can more fully understand the kind of questions we'd prefer to deal with.

Comment: I love the grittiness of this answer. So honest. Yeh, I had to delete all my auto comments after the welcoming blog came out this year. Many of them, crafted with "good intentions I guess" would fail the CoC test

Comment: The third point is interesting. I favor the creation of a meta page which clearly states that SO is not a code-writing service, but in a nice informative way, like the [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)  or similar pages.

Comment: My only quarrel with this answer is that your point #3 presumes that *"this problem in particular"* is well-defined. As I argue in my answer, I don't think that's the case; rather, I think "SO is not a code-writing service" gets used in response to a whole bunch of distinct problems (and some non-problems that don't deserve criticism at all).

Comment: I guess I will never know what Stack Overflow is Not:  "This question was removed from Meta Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation."

Answer (score 7):

When I see a question where the poster is essentially asking for someone to write their program for them, I'll generally leave a comment something like the following:

> Can you provide some clarifying information as to what part of this requirement you're having trouble with? If you're stuck on a specific point, try to describe it and we can try to help. Without focusing on a specific issue, though, your question is too broad to be an on-topic Stack Overflow question and may be closed.

Instead of saying "You're asking us to write your whole program for you, which is bad and wrong", my angle is to suggest "Here's what you could do to increase the chances that you're going to get the outcome you're looking for". I feel like it's a more welcoming, less confrontational way to phrase the point that generally gets a better reaction - or at least, elicits a poor reaction less of the time.

Rather than just telling people what *not* to do, I try to at least nudge them in the direction of what they *should* be doing instead.

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted within less than ten seconds of being posted - if anyone has feedback, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Doesn't this already exist? *"too broad
Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."* or even *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, <snip>"*

Comment: @KevinB - sure, that's a close vote reason, and one that I'll often use. But if I feel that it's worth also leaving a personal comment to the poster, this is more or less the template I use.

Answer (score 7):

A question of the type "Write my code" will most likely be...

1. Broad
2. Unclear
3. Lacking details
4. Not showing research effort

...or some combination thereof.

---

So, we can ask the questioner to please address these issues:

1. Narrow the scope of the question
2. Clarify what you're asking
3. Add more details
4. Describe what you have tried and show your code

Thus, no need to comment "Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service."

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly what I wanted to say when I found this question today, and far more succinct than what I would have written.

Answer (score 7):

Why are those comments flagged though? I am glad if I can help a person with their coding problems. When I see a vague question, I ask them for a `[mcve]` or for more information. Or giving away pointers. I do not want to write out a whole solution. Yet those comments appears at questions that are either requirement dumps or are very obvious assigned task that the OP has to work out. It may sound hard but in all those situations, they (employee) are being paid or (students) are being instructed to work out a programmable solution to a problem. Not we, volunteers that spend our time by contributing to StackOverflow by helping others with their coding issues, have to work it out for them. I have helped others. I also got aid from others on my questions here. I also have learned new things by checking other questions. That is why I like StackOverflow.

If a person dumps such questions, then it has to be made clear to him that StackOverflow is not a coding service. There are other services that he can use (like freelance coding service). Of course you can close vote the question. But that does not help the end user because he would experience it as "unwelcoming", that his question got closed with a generic message with a generic reason.

A comment (under some conditions though: do it in a civil manner please) is appropriate for this. The truth has to be said and we know that truth can hurt sometimes.

Comment: `Why are those comments flagged though?` Because they don't help. Help should be specific, not a general statement on the purpose of SO. Being right isn't the same as being helpful.

Comment: I also  don't understand the need to flag such comments, there are lots of other things to flag :) I feel like we're taking "rudiness" to a whole new radical level.

Comment: @Cristik, I often flag such comments as "It's no longer needed." In my opinion, it's *never* needed. A comment stating what the purpose of SO is not doesn't really do anything, except occasionally offend a sensitive asker.

Comment: @jpp: if you vote to close for other reasons, you are supposed to give a reason and that reason gets posted as a comment. What reason would you use for the question “I want a grid with 3 columns”?

Comment: @jmoreno, Too broad. In fact, most if not all "give me the codez" questions are too broad.

Comment: @jpp: and when the answer to that is an edit refining the requirements?  First column has first name...

Comment: @jmoreno, I'm not sure what you are arguing. How does this relate to whether or not we should be opining on the purpose of SO in a comment? Seems like such a statement, while correct, belongs more on a blog post.

Comment: @jpp: there are 5 categories for closing a question, the one that best describes “code please” is off topic, which is INHERENTLY opining about the purpose of SO. If you vote to close as off topic and give a reason why you think it is off topic, that will result in a comment being posted to the question, not a blog post. If a post is off topic, and you close it for a different reasons, you are telling them if they fix the wrong thing their question will be acceptable. That’s untrue and likely to lead to a waste of everyone’s time.

Comment: `If a post is off topic, and you close it for a different reasons`. "Too broad" is not "a different" reason for a "Give me the codez" question, to me it's the *precise* reason! I'm confused as to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's important to point out what the comment actually says: "**We** are not a code writing service.". This is a comment which refers to the Stack Overflow community. It tells the person asking who we are. Therefore it's not (direct) criticism of the person asking the question.

Of course, the comment is written in reaction to the person asking a poor question, but the comment is phrased so that it doesn't say anything directly negative about either the question or any person in particular.

Of course, the comment is not perfect. It could be phrased to say what Stack Overflow is, instead of saying what it is not. But let's not lose focus. The problem is yet another homework dump. Bikeshedding about the exact wording of the comments is missing the point.

Comment: *"The problem is yet another homework dump. "* - well, it might or might not be. Good questions are unfairly criticised all the time.

Answer (score 0):

On #1 and #2, I tend to agree with [Nicol's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372169/2751851), and in particular with:

> If you can't do better than saying what SO is not, then it's probably best to just downvote and move on.

On alternative ways of stating it, a while ago, in an unrelated discussion, I suggested the following hypothetical comment:

> Please [edit] your question to make it about a specific issue you had while trying to solve this problem. Exact reproductions of homework problems are not a good fit for this site, as questions here should be useful not just to askers, but to other readers.

A little verbose, maybe, but it at least sets some positive expectation and suggests a course of action.

Comment: Like many of the other suggested comments here, I feel as though the advice in your proposed comment is a recipe for bad questions. Editing an already problematic question to additionally include a specific problem the asker encountered along the way is likely to make it *worse*, not better; since it leaves them basically asking two questions in one ("how do I solve the original problem?" and "why doesn't this approach work?") whose answers may not even be particularly related to each other.

Comment: @MarkAmery Perhaps it makes it a little clearer to change "edit your question to point out a specific issue [...]" into "edit your question to make it about a specific issue [...]" -- I have just changed it to that.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a significant improvement; I can imagine questions where this would be reasonable advice, now.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who repeatedly finds questions such as these, I always take the time to think about what a suitable comment would be for this, usually, it's a case of DV and flag as too broad, however, in some instances, the OP may genuinely not understand the rules of Stack Overflow (for instance, new users, whom this mainly seems to come from), the comment I usually find effective is along the lines of;

> Have you tried anything to achieve this? Are you able to share this with us? If so, please can you provide an [mcve] so that we can find the best answer for you, a lack of code ultimately does not lead to a good answer and your learning, rather, someone providing the answer for you. Ultimately - at Stack Overflow, we are not here to write the answer for you, rather to help you fix issues and gain an understanding of what has gone wrong in your code

Obviously, this is over verbose, it is intended to lean the questioneer to finding an answer for themselves first, either by adding code they have or by using something like the search on here or Google-fu to find tutorials / documentation

Comment: Too verbose IMO. I exclude `so that we can find...` Sometimes, less is more.

Comment: @jpp - thanks for the suggestion, will take it on board :)

Comment: I would not be surprised to see a comment like that flagged because it starts with "Have you tried anything to achieve this?" (envision an OP going "! How dare you question me?!") . Not a criticism btw, just something I have a feeling will happen. +1 for meantioning to include a link to the MCVE page :)

Answer (score -3):

It seems like half the time the OP responds with something like, "I don't want the code written for me, I just want help/advice/point in the right direction". So telling someone "We are not a code writing service" is likely being seen as a false accusation.

> How can we write them to be helpful?

Just tell people what needs to be changed in order to make their post a good question. For example, "Any good answer to your question would be too long for Stack Overflow. Please edit it to make it more specific." We don't have to assume the worst in order to tell someone their question is too broad.

Comment: How do we make that scale?

Comment: @Makoto Make what scale?

Comment: The guidance that you're proposing.

Comment: @Makoto All I did was suggest an alternative comment. I'm not arguing that the number of comments should change.

Comment: Great, then we have people telling us saying "Please edit it to make it more specific" is unwelcoming because it is assuming I haven't already made it as specific as I'm able to

Comment: The people that "want help/advice" are just as bad https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm not arguing that their response makes the question OK, just that the OP is very likely to argue that they don't actually want code written for them.

Comment: I agree with you. They often comment or counter flag with that response "I'm not asking you to write .. bla bla"

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton if people want to flag perfectly reasonable comments as unfriendly, they will be declined.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I understand that, but how is the flag invalid? If that person feels unwelcomed by it, surely it's unwelcoming, right? What makes "Make this more specific" less unwelcoming than "We are not a code writing service"? To me, it's just opinion. I don't think either one is unwelcoming (One is a fact stating why the question is unanswerable, one is a request to make the question answerable, I'm not really negotiating which of these sentences is "better" for the end user, but that it's impossible to set rules stating what is and is not "unwelcoming", yet _someone_ does.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton because the flag is not only subjective, it has to be balanced with objectivity. Is the comment unwelcoming to a reasonable person? Yes/No. Accordingly. Also some people flag anything they don't agree with and that type of vindictive flagging is not on. I personally draw a line in the sand. That's why I have tended to decline, but still delete the comments, to get them out of the way.

Comment: @YvetteColomb What defines a "reasonable person"? Especially since it seems this issue is very split and people have varying opinions about it, a "reasonable person" is not a black/white issue. I'm sure there is a ton of people that don't find "We are not a code writing service" to not be unwelcoming.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ah, well the mods are supposed to be the voice of the "reasonable person" which is why I put this out for a community consensus. What does everyone think? Should we be deleting these comments? Marking the flags as helpful or declining them? It's a combination of common sense, feeling out if a flagger is genuinely distressed or actually dishing out more abuse than they're receiving. None of it is clear cut. And I'm not covering it all succinctly in the comments like this.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I definitely appreciate you posting this and gathering a consensus, I have no interest in personally calling anyone out, and I think you are doing a great job, and I know this is all community discussion and what not. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @GrumpyCrouton it's really good to get encouragement sometimes. Yeh, I get defensive writing comments.. people will sometimes jump on them if they're not complete.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I think it's normal to get defensive when you feel like you are doing the right thing, and you think someone is telling you that you're not. But I'm not telling you you're doing the wrong thing, I'm just trying to demonstrate how hard it is to define clear rules for defining words on your screen when you can't define the motive behind the comment.

Comment: I almost want to +1 this, since I agree completely with everything up until the last sentence, but I'm not sure what the bit at the end about assuming malice is about. It's not obvious to me that "we are not a code-writing service" implies any assumption that the asker is acting maliciously.

Comment: @MarkAmery it's the idea that the asker is purposefully asking an overly broad question, or purposefully posting their entire homework problem without attempting to solve the problem themselves first. That rather people might just have ended up at the ask question part after any unknown amount of trying and researching only to ask a question that was too broad. I think "we don't need to assume the worst" or "assume good faith" would fit better there.

Answer (score -18):

Someone needs help of some kind.
You either help, or you don't.
Why do you feel the need to tell that person, and everyone else within hearing, that you are not going to help this person, and then continue to add some irrelevant reason as to why not (and soon there's a whole gang of stone-throwers).
What's your point, exactly? What do you achieve? (NOT directed at Yvette, but at commenters in general. ;) )

Comment: You make a good point. The way you've worded it, it sounds like you're addressing me personally. Perhaps consider editing it to direct it towards commenters?

Comment: _"Possible duplicate of X"_, _"This question is off-topic here, see site Y"_, _"Your question has no MCVE"_. Yea, why would we comment when we won't answer a question? To help the OP improve their question, of course!

Comment: @YvetteColomb: :) relects my state-of-mind right now: writing an app that uses many dynamic threads and somewhere in one of these threads there's a bug...

Comment: @Cerbrus: but these example answers you give are indeed helpful, and should not be seen/used as sticks.

Comment: @slashmais: Except they're often perceived to be sticks by OP that want nothing but an answer. And then we're called "unwelcoming".

Comment: @Cerbrus: Just so. (see my answer)