# How to put a condemnation more lightly

Tags: discussion

I saw this question on Stack Overflow: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777986/custom-wordpress-menu-using-walker*

The person was pretty much saying, "I need a navigation menu, do this and this and this. Anybody can do it for me?"

I was obviously very angry, because this person thought Stack Overflow users were people to be used, so I replied this:

> Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. We are not your slaves who do all your thinking for you

One hour later I came back and saw user `Jon P` post:

> @awesomeguy perhaps you might want to rephrase your comment given our new Code Of Conduct

I decided to change, only to figure out that I couldn't anymore (it passed the time frame for editing). But if I could edit it, to still keep the condemning tone, but make it not so mean (which that person actually kind of deserves), what would I say?

**EDIT:** Someone actually upvoted this post for some reason.

Comment: @JK. That too, but they are literally ordering people like they hired them

Comment: I tried asking this on ISP(Interpersonal Skills) but they said it should be asked on SO meta

Comment: Just close-vote and move on. Don't waste time on questions like that.

Comment: *"I was obviously very angry"* - well, time to work on that problem.

Comment: *I was obviously very angry* don't be. It is not worth your energy. And I can  assure that you look very silly while yelling and cursing at your screen...

Comment: Remember that a low effort post is best addressed by a least effort response. The down vote button is one-mouse-click way. If you're generous you flag for closure, that needs 4 mouse-clicks. Don't use your keyboard for those questions.

Comment: Related: [We-are-not-a-code-writing-service comments. Are they the good, the bad or the ugly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372166/2821954)

Comment: @rene do use your keyboard: `?` (Show menu), `M`oderate, `F`lag, `3` (Should be closed), `3` (Unclear what you're asking), `Enter`. If you're creative, the M-F sequence can be used as an expletive (albeit in your head only).

Comment: @CodeCaster Ha, I was wondering who it would be that offered that option ;) .... kudos to you.

Comment: @rene I do have to admit I hardly use it. Mainly to `G`o `H`ome.

Comment: You'll have to find more joy in downvoting such a question.  Takes a bit of practice, you've done it only 5 times so far and that isn't enough to get the look-and-feel :)  But there's a lot of bang behind that buck, that question is going to stink up the place for only 9 days before it gets auto-deleted and you'll help other SO users from wasting their time on it.  Can't get that kind of bang from a snarky comment.  Also voting to close is too much effort and not really necessary.

Comment: Learn something new every day - thanks @CodeCaster

Comment: I'm not a fan of the new code of conduct at all. Act like a moron and get what you deserve. I will definitely be commenting less and just flag to close with no explanation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the joys of being a part of this community is the ever-present opportunity to run into a question that *demands* immediate service or action. You ask about how you can put condemnation more lightly and I would suggest that you can't.

When coming across a question like the one you mention, it's best to use the tools that the platform readily provides, namely (1) downvoting and (2) flagging.

Don't waste your energy in posting something that you're likely going to regret. However, if you must type out a condemning reply for cathartic reasons, do as my fellow CM suggested to me once:

> "Type out your response, but **don't hit** send." -- [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija)

Comment: I often mis-click sending a response by accident ...

Comment: I've never accidentally hi

Comment: thanks this is really helpful, I think it will help me calm down and get the frustration out

Answer (score 4):

I think the lightest way you could condemn something like this is to simply

## downvote and/or vote to close as appropriate

without leaving a comment, and **move on** with your day.  Engaging with an OP who believes that it's okay to dump work on the site only invites the opportunity for an argument; by walking away, you **eliminate** that opportunity.

You can be upset.  But being upset at someone on the Internet over this is tantamount to shouting at a wall.  Do whatever you need to in order to detox and destress, but the strong sentiment here is **don't directly engage with an OP** in this fashion.

Comment: That begs for [the obligatory xkcd reference](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/386:_Duty_Calls) (386).