# When is it correct to re-do changes that the author intentionally rolled back?

Tags: discussion, specific-edit, rollback-wars

Another user recently edited an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57275760) of mine to remove this footer which came after a code suggestion for the answer:

> Do note the comment attached to your question. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. The community here expects you to try yourself and to show where you're stuck.

I saw this, and felt that it changed my answer in a poor way.  It probably doesn't matter much as the question has been closed, by people I respect, for good reasons.  But I didn't like the change, and I reverted to the previous version, with a minor edit, since the comment it referenced was now gone.

That user came along a few minutes later, once again deleted the footer, and locked the edits for a few days.

Is that appropriate?  I've never been in an edit war here, but it seems that unless the content is abusive, there should be some deference to the author of the material.  Am I missing something?  Should I re-rollback after the lock window?  Flag this action somehow?  Do something else?

Comment: “I saw this, and felt that it changed my answer in a poor way. It probably doesn't matter much as the question has been closed, by people I respect, for good reasons.” - I always remove pointless unnecessary commentary like the quoted text from contributions. If what I remove was reversed I would immediately flag for a moderation to inject themselves into the situation and just downvote the contribution for having unnecessary content contained within it. Rule of them don’t get into an edit war with a community moderator (or anyone).

Comment: I guess I'd better look up "diamond moderator".  But I've rolled back someone's changes to my content fewer than a dozen times, I would think.  I've never had them re-do it.  So this is new to me.  I'm curious if there is some guideline to describe what you're calling "pointless unnecessary commentary".  Mostly I reserve things like that for comments, but if I do happen to answer a question that I think still needs work, I add it there.  This is the first time I've seen any negative response to it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Rolling back an edit once, might be acceptable, if you’re doing it twice you probably should stop and ask yourself the reason your own edit was rolled back. Mentioning what an acceptable question is, within the body of an answer, is sort of pointless. If the question isn’t acceptable then you probably shouldn’t be answering it. Meta commentary like the quoted text isn’t required or relevant when submitting an answer to a question. 47k reputation and you don’t know that?

Comment: @SecurityHound.  I only rolled back once.  I then edited the rolled back post to slightly reword the now out-of-date text I'd restored.  I couldn't have rolled back again, as the post was locked.

Comment: I can't even remember the last time that a years-old question or answer was edited, the original author rolled back the edit, and I thought that said author was even remotely in the right. Unilateral edits come from a relatively small pool - users with 2k+ reputation with an active interest in editing - and otherwise they have to get approved by two other users.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That was *removed* because, well, it's not a material part of an answer to the question.  Even better, it was removed by a diamond moderator.

Then [you added it *back* a couple of times](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57275760/revisions).  This is an obvious rollback war in which the resolution is to lock the post until everyone cools off.

Ultimately the answer is, that comment doesn't belong in the answer block *full stop*, and should be removed from the answer *full stop*.

Please don't add it again; it's really not a critical part of the answer, and no one needs to see that when they're searching for an answer to this specific question.

Comment: Well, I rolled it back once, and then edited it because the wording was slightly off after a comment it mentioned had been deleted.  I've only done minor amounts of moderation and have no idea what a diamond moderator is.  (Don't explain; I'll look it up.)  But is it some sort of community guideline not to suggest that the author do some more work first?  Or is that appropriate only in comments, and not answers?

Comment: It's really not appropriate *anywhere*, but there are ways to express one's discontent with a question that don't involve you commentating on a question or answer.  If you don't think the question is good, downvote it.  If you don't think the question is on-topic, vote to close it.  Neither of these actions require you to add additional commentary on how you feel the OP came to ask this question of us on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Interesting, because I feel like downvotes, and votes to close are the big guns, and a comment explaining how the content is lacking is much more helpful.  Again, is this philosophy documented somewhere as the preferred SO behavior?

Comment: Comments don't help the system determine what it needs to do with the content. If users are repeatedly posting content that needs to be updated to be useful... and noone ever indicates to the system that they're posting not useful content... the system can never do anything about it.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know of anything off the top of my head that *explicitly* says "don't say this", @ScottSauyet.  I figured it was more along the lines of common sense that if you were answering a question, your answer only contained *the answer* you wanted to provide, without extra commentary (which could be edited out in the future if needed).  It's also common courtesy to not tell someone how much their approach to asking a question of you sucked or fell short in such a way while you provide an answer.  But perhaps that's just me...

Comment: Well, I'm not convinced.  Clearly from the votes to this question, I'm in the minority.  But I feel as though I wasn't being even slightly discourteous, just trying to help a user improve her question-asking skills, and that is an attempt to improve the community as a whole.  It seems to me that *only the answer* leads too easily to low-quality code-only answers.  I'm bothered because I feel like this is an attempt to improve the community; but the community is clearly telling me that it's not helpful.  :-(

Comment: @ScottSauyet Frame challenge: Where is “The community here expects you to try yourself and to show where you're stuck.” documented?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users which is linked to directly from the help article

Comment: @ScottSauyet if you want to fight the change please make sure to address  "This information is false" description of the edit - if you insist on adding wrong information to a post the post should be downvoted (many people are quite unhappy with downvotes - making others to downvote your post is ... strange).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Oh, no.  I'd rather simply delete the answer, or just leave it as is.  But as  the Q/A Kevin B linked to seems to imply, the information was not wrong (except for the minor peccadillo of referring to a now-deleted comment.)  Don't we expect question-writers to put in some effort at solving their problems before posting?

Comment: @KevinB It doesn't say that in the linked post.

Comment: “Interesting, because I feel like downvotes, and votes to close are the big guns, and a comment explaining how the content is lacking is much more helpful.” - If a question reads like the author is asking for code, then how is it helpful to the community, and how are you doing the community a service by answering such a low quality question? Little late to delete your answer, you have already submitted the answer, deleting it at this point would contribute to what many believe is toxic behavior. A small minority of users, delete any contribution, that is negatively received.

Comment: @ScottSauyet *"just trying to help a user improve her question-asking skills"* - like any decent human being would. Unfortunately Stack Overflow does not really have the tools to do so, except for meta or a chat room. People who try to teach through this site tend to have miserable times which is not unusual when you use a tool in a way that is not intended. Better stick to answering questions and setting examples and hope that people pick up things on their own.

Answer (score 13):

First of all, your answer was about JavaScript. The part I removed is in no way related to your answer. At best it's metacommentary about the question itself. It should have never been part of the answer. It was wrong to put it back in and that's exactly why I locked the post.

When it comes to making comments like this, we highly discourage them. If this text was part of an actual comment, the comment would be removed. See [We-are-not-a-code-writing-service comments. Are they the good, the bad, or the ugly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372166/1839439). Many people consider these comments unkind, but it all depends on how it's phrased. However you feel about them, we really do not need to tell the asker that they are lazy and they should do their work themselves. Why? It's because...

Stack Overflow is a questions and answers site. It might not be a code-writing service, but it's also not a help desk, forum, ticketing system, tutoring site, or any other kind of personal service. We do not care how much effort the asker put into solving the issue themselves. **As long as it's a new and answerable question, we take it. We do not require effort beyond the effort necessary in writing a good question.** The question may be a homework assignement, interview question, or an actual task as part of one's job and it doesn't matter.

Remarks like the one I removed are also hypocritical. We provide code in our answers. Therefore, we are a code-writing service in some capacity. We are not going to write a whole app or fulfill every coding request. We provide code that's only necessary to explain the solution. So if someone asks "How do I write a function to..." we can provide a complete function, but the more important aspect of the answer will be the step-by-step explanation of how to write the function  ourselves.

If the question asks for too much, vote to close as "needs focus".

If you feel like a mechanical turk and you believe that providing an answer to the question is not going to help future visitors, don't answer. Downvote instead.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm sorry I didn't recognize that this was a moderator comment. I've seen the `Mod` tag next to people's names in answers, and did know that meant "Moderator", but that's not on the edits page. I had no idea the diamond meant the same thing, and didn't even think about what it was. "We do not require effort beyond the effort necessary in writing a good question." But what does that effort entail? I suppose that phrasing is hypocritical, and I don't usually use the "code-writing" phrasing. I'll avoid that from now on. In any case, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @ScottSauyet By question writing effort I mean whatever is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Check for grammar, typos, noise (thanks, please help, I'm a beginner, etc.), MCVE if needed, good descriptive title. And most importantly we require people to search for their question before posting so that they don't ask duplicate questions.

Comment: Ok, well I see that amount of effort as the price of entry, the barest of minimums.  I find https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593 much more compelling, and that also seems to be at least semi-officially blessed as part of the community faq.  In respose to a question of required effort it states, "A lot. Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer," and goes on to detail expected work.  That seems a better standard for improving the signal-noise ratio than what you suggest.

Comment: "The question may be a homework assignement, interview question, or an actual task as part of one's job and it doesn't matter." - As a practical matter, though, none of these ever make answerable, clear, focused questions as is. Which is a big part of why the [corresponding FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) exists.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I wrestled with the same apparent contradiction for months, and eventually realized that there *really isn't remotely as much conflict as there appears to be*. Some of the discussion in the meta that you linked, and the one I linked, is out of date, but overall the picture is fairly clear. Asking a question that is properly specific and focused on a single issue, and (for "why" questions) includes a really proper MCVE that in particular is really M, **takes a lot of work**. Between that and searching for duplicates, that really does account for the high "research effort" bar.

Answer (score 1):

### Regarding how (and where) you said it

First off: locking is only doable by diamond moderators (and up: i.e. "Community Managers" and Stack Overflow staff). In particular, the "moderation tools" [granted at 10,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) do not include this.

If something happens on a website that involves just you and a moderator, and it leads to a moderator taking a moderator-exclusive action, there are effectively two possibilities: either you have a complaint about a moderator abuse of power, **or you are being rightly censured**.

For Stack Overflow, asking on Meta is the right way to check whether something is an abuse of power, assuming that you can't reason it out with common sense; and it's also the right way to start doing something about it. However, a moderator action *that prevents you from doing what you were doing* (i.e., in this case, engaging in a rollback war) should always be treated as a cease **and desist**. No matter what community this was, no matter what suspicion you had that the moderator was in the wrong, it would never, ever, ever be right to "re-rollback after the lock window" (or the equivalent). Even in cases where an investigation into the matter found that you were 100% in the right and that whatever you were editing should be in the state you wanted to roll back to, *that should be done by either a (now-crow-eating) moderator, or by a third party.*

> StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. The community here expects you to try yourself and to show where you're stuck.

Accepting for now that such *commentary* is appropriate, it should be a *comment* on the question. **Not anywhere within an answer**, and not as a comment on your own answer (because it pertains to the question, not the answer). After all, since Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, questions and answers should not contain discussion.

> Do note the comment attached to your question.

If it was your own comment, then you have already said everything that needs to be said. If it was someone else's comment, you could upvote it.

### Regarding what to say

We want OPs to [show research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), yes - **because it helps to clarify questions, not** as a barrier to demonstrating that one "deserves" an answer.

Stack Overflow is, indeed, not a code-writing service: code written to spec constitutes an *implementation of functionality, not an answer to a question*. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, so we answer questions, rather than writing code to implement functionality. However, the purpose of "expecting OP to try" is to **identify a problem concretely**, and of "showing where OP is stuck" is to **focus** on that problem and **communicate a corresponding question**.

Please do not express your frustration with OP's laziness on the site, in any form. The best response is your own laziness: just ignore the question, if you really consider it "below your pay grade". (I personally am happy to give in-depth answers to questions that are "easy" - as long as they can plausibly come about from a genuine lack of knowledge.)

Meanwhile, note the advice in [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Answer well-asked questions". Typically, a failure by the OP to "try something", or to show a sticking point, will result in a question that **Needs More Focus**, or occasionally which **Needs Details or Clarity**. If that is an actual issue - i.e., *if solving the problem entails following multiple steps*, or if you as a would-be answerer are *not sure which step OP wants to know about* - **then please vote to close the question, rather than answering**.

Comment: In my own defense, note that as described above, I had no idea I was dealing with a moderator.  AFAIK, this was my first interaction with one. I now know that the diamond and the ability to lock posts are signs of one. I rarely answer low-quality questions, unless there are already reasonable answers but I think I have a better one.  I seem to be far from the consensus view about the relative merits of downvoting/close-voting versus commenting. I feel like a downvote without a comment is just lazy and rarely helps turn the poster into a better community member. Definitely a minority on this.

Comment: "I feel like a downvote without a comment is just lazy and rarely helps turn the poster into a better community member. Definitely a minority on this." Not really; people commonly make that argument on Meta. It's just that there are a lot of people around who have tried to make those comments, and become jaded with the responses they provoke. I do endorse the use of comments directly on the question, in the comment section. Re the diamonds, I agree that Stack Exchange's visual language leaves something to be desired; but most of what moderators do here is intended to be fairly unobtrusive.

Comment: @ScottSauyet regardless of what most participants want, the decision of someone choosing not to leave a comment is to be respected. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr