# Official policy on how Stack Exchange responds to requests for support for academic honesty violations

Tags: support

Sites like Chegg, which claim to be a learning aid and not a repository of solved coursework, often offer policies on academic honesty, and provide mechanisms and pathways for instructors and administrators to interact with the site to pursue such matters. For example, right on the Chegg.com honesty page, https://www.chegg.com/honorcode, it offers:

> For Professors: If you have concerns that students may be using our
>   products inappropriately, Chegg is here to work with you and address
>   your concerns. We will cooperate with any official investigation by an
>   academic instruction. To open an official Honor Code investigation in
>   conjunction with an academic investigation, the request must come
>   directly from the office of the dean or the body in charge of handling
>   matters of academic investigation at the university. The written
>   request must be made on university letterhead and indicate that the
>   information is needed as part of an official school investigation into
>   academic integrity. The letter should be dated, signed and please
>   include URLs or any other information that is relevant to the
>   investigation. You can scan and email the letter back to
>   honorcode@chegg.com or fax it to: (408) 521-0400.

After hearing Stack Exchange pop up in a variety of internal discussions, and now seeing a question that leads me to believe that such issues may be popping up -- does the Stack Exchange network have any relevant policies?

Specifically, how would a solicitation from a university agent for support in such a situation be responded to? Are such requests handled uniformly, by policy, or handled ad hoc? Are the policies outward-facing, so relevant parties can find them? If not, should clear policies be in place?

More specifically, if a representative of a school has an academic honesty issue with a question, is there a clear path to admins for help with a dishonesty case, and if approached with such a request, what is the "official" policy under which Stack Exchange will respond?

Will such support be offered, or will the request be ignored?

Comment: These issues have existed for a while, and while I'm unaware of any specific policy, there exists avenues for an institution to get in touch with Stack Overflow should they need to.

Comment: How do you identify a question as coursework let identify the issue of what would be considered academic dishonesty? Some places would say looking for information on a site like this is not allowed while others would encourage it,

Comment: @Stijn -- this isn't a duplicate of that.  The real question, which I'll try to edit to clarify, is that if a representative of a school has an academic honesty issue with a question, is there a clear path to admins for help with a dishonesty case, and if approached with such a request, what is the "official" policy under which SE will respond?

Comment: Have you read [Tim Post's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366999/so-is-being-used-as-a-real-time-cheating-platform/367025#367025)? *"We recommend just answering questions that grab your interest, and don't worry so much about intent. [...] But people sometimes cheat, and there's little to do about that. But if they leave a lasting helpful artifact in the wake, well? :)"* So there's no "academic honesty" policy on SO.

Comment: @JoeW -- let's say that, for example, a professor sees an original figure from a homework assignment or exam?

Comment: @Makoto  -- I suggest that the ad hoc approach be reduced to something official

Comment: What do you want SO to do? The dishonesty is not an SO problem, it's a school problem. What is it you are actually asking for?

Comment: @ScottSeidman: When you see a figure appearing at SO that you created, then I suggest you claim a copyright infringe. This is at least what I would do when students copy large portions of assignment code to SO.

Comment: @Stijn -  this question is NOT about who should respond to what, or how.  It's about how SE responds to a request for information from a school's agent.

Comment: Unless the school is asking for content to be removed for copyright reasons how would you expect them to respond? Should a question be removed based on a claim that someone is using it to cheat in school? I also am not sure that you can compare Chegg to Stack Exchange since Chegg is specifically targeted it homework help and Stack Exchange sites are general question and answer sites where there is no way to differentiate between a student, professional or casual user.

Comment: @BDL -- This isn't a copyright infringement issue.  Of course, that's available, as are cease and desists.  That's not responsive to this question.  I've tried to clarify by posting the Chegg policy.

Comment: I'll retract my duplicate vote since you're so convinced it's not a duplicate. But is it not clear from that answer by Tim (who is an employee), that they are not really concerned by "academic honesty" and instead care more about the content being useful?

Comment: @Stijn -- thanks for retracting the close vote.  "Concern" about academic honesty is quite a different issue than "will the platform offer support for those pursuing honesty violations?"

Comment: @JoeW, for example, an electronic record of posting times, the edit trail for edits to hide cheating, all the way up to policies on sharing account information (the latter will likely never happen, but the policy should be written down in this context!)

Comment: @Stijn -- thanks for changing the tag.  Much better.

Comment: Well posting times and edit trails are already available to all users and don't require any help from Stack Exchange (outside of a deleted question answer but that is solved by enough rep). As for the account sharing information it will be pretty hard if not impossible to link an account on the site to a user at the university especially if they are trying to cover their tracks.

Comment: Homework questions are not forbidden in SO as far as I know as long as they are good questions which are likely to help others. Of course that means that the question would be for a specific programming problem and not about someone doing your whole coursework for you. In that aspect I don't think this is such a big problem as it would be for a page which specialises in providing complete coursework solutions.

Comment: I'm sure if you used the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of every page, someone would help with whatever issue was presented, related to "academic dishonesty" or not...

Comment: @JoeW -- sure.  Notwithstanding, whatever the policy is, becomes, should be, etc, is a matter for discussion  -- the question really is "is there a policy, and is it written down and accessible"?

Comment: In that case I think your answer is in the duplicate that there is no policy

Comment: @JoeW -- it's closed, fine.  My question about  how SE would respond to such a request remains unanswered.  Perhaps I should ask that specifically, or edit this question, as I think that issue should receive attention.

Comment: I think paying attention to our approach is going to yield dividends on how your question would be answered.  Considering that we allow homework questions (as long as they meet our standards), and we generally pay no attention to the poster or their intent, I don't see why that doesn't answer your question.  Is an official policy of, "We care about the content, not it's origin", really going to add anything to the discussion?

Comment: @fbueckert -- so, if I'm a prof, and I contact SE (by whatever mechanism), and say, "There is a clear indication that question X violated the academic honesty policy at Frostbite Falls University.  Can you please provide me with the IP address of the poster?", the reply would be ????  I'm requesting that *we should all know* what that reply is.  Honestly, I don't know how SE would respond.  Is that an unreasonable ask?  If there is no answer, I suggest that SE might well think about it.

Comment: The reply would be, "No, that is private information, we will not provide that."  I don't understand how a professor should have access to more information than anyone else on the site, or why.  Our approach to academics is purely focused on the content, and if it meets our standards.

Comment: @fbueckert  I have no problem if that were the reply- though I don't believe that you *know* what the answer would be.  Why would you?  Have you asked that question, and gotten that answer?  If you have some special reason why you would know, I can accept that, too.  I still suggest that SE should openly publish that policy, because there are reasons why they should, and no reasons why they shouldn't.

Comment: I don't think it's an unreasonable assumption; which site do you know of that will give you user logs without a court order?  As far as I know, not a single one would.  IPs, by themselves, are not anything special worth protecting, but it is telling how other information *is*.  Any that did, would be sites I'd want to avoid, because if they're sharing that, what *other*, more personal information, are they sharing without informing anyone?  With some familiarity of the network, that specific piece of info is private, available to moderators only.

Comment: @fbueckert -- yes-- I do know of such a site!  Chegg, for one.  I posted their policy above, which is to cooperate with academic honesty investigations.  This is why I asked about SE.  I'll try one more time, and then I promise I'll stop.  I'm not trying to argue about what the policy should be!!!!!  I'm asking what it is, and if it doesn't exist, I'm suggesting that there should be a uniform policy, and that it should be published.  If the policy is "Honesty inquiries shall be responded to by emailing Monty Python clips to the requester" -- FINE!!  Write it down, and live with it.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what the end goal is of even having an official policy on academic honesty.  Okay, so we get one.  Now what?  What does it help? Will it change how you interact with the site?  Will others?  I see no value in any end goal, which is why I'm so confused about your insistence on having one.

Comment: @fbueckert -- you'd be much more interested in such issues if you spent substantial time in honesty hearings, listening to students who have no idea that they committed violations that are clear to everybody else in the room.  Students are a significant stakeholder of SE, and clear policies can only serve the students better.  Educators are a clear stakeholder of SE, and want to see the resource being used by students in the most pedagogically valuable way possible. You might not be in a constituency that finds such discussion valuable.  There's nothing wrong with that.  Others do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194898/discussion-between-fbueckert-and-scott-seidman).

Comment: If having such policy results in more Monty Python clips, count me in.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I think at least part of the pushback you're getting here is that SE users are very privacy conscious, and SE has a track record of stating again and again not to violate that privacy, and what you're citing as examples is basically extrajudicially giving out personal information of users to a university, which might be legal in the US, but nonetheless may find little support here.

Comment: @Magisch It would be legal *if SO's privacy policy stated it may gave out your data in that situation*.  It's not legal if their privacy policy states that they won't.  That's also going to apply to most any country.  I'd be pretty shocked to find a country where you could provide a contract stating you won't give private data away, except in specifically described ways, and then give it to some private 3rd party not meeting those criteria and have it not be violating that contract.

Answer (score 21):

We've had plenty of these requests come through the support system in the past, and the response has always been the same: we cannot assist you.

We do not have any policy that bypasses our privacy policy for suspected cases of academic dishonesty, and we **will not** provide anyone with private information of users. We generally advise them of our Acceptable Use Policy regarding DMCA in case any copyrights were violated in the posting of a question, but that is pretty much the extent of the conversation we will have. I don't think anyone has ever followed up with a DMCA or claimed copyright in any of those cases.

Comment: How about making deleted posts, deleted comments and other previously-public things in the history of a question accessible? PII is off limits of course, but what about posting times and edit trails as mentioned elsewhere in the comments?

Comment: @Bergi Honestly, I'm not sure. We've never had a request from an educator for trying to get information about now-deleted content before. We've mostly declined to assist when regular users try to get us to dump content from deleted questions for them, though, so I can't imagine we'd change that for this situation. Probably just direct them to Data Explorer if it's still available there.

Comment: @Bergi Most of that could probably be obtained with sleuthing and the assistance of a 10k user, so they wouldn't need to go through SE directly for that. Thats at least for deleted posts.

Answer (score 15):

To find out who SO is able to give private information to, see the Privacy Policy and the Legal section, as that covers under what situations users' private information will be given out.

I'm not a lawyer, but my reading of the relevant sections doesn't provide any provision for giving private information to people claiming to represent academic institutions investigating academic dishonestly complaints.

But the privacy policy is the Official Policy on what SO can do with your private data.  It's even legally binding.